# What's the difference between the various methods to get an Android Context?

Tags: android, android-context

In various bits of Android code I've seen:

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void method() {
       mContext = this;    // since Activity extends Context
       mContext = getApplicationContext();
       mContext = getBaseContext();
    }
 }
```

However I can't find any decent explanation of which is preferable, and under what circumstances which should be used.

Pointers to documentation on this, and guidance about what might break if the wrong one is chosen, would be much appreciated.

Comment: This link might help you. Go through [this](http://droidpassion.blogspot.in/2012/03/all-about-context.html)..

Answer (score 313, accepted):

I agree that documentation is sparse when it comes to Contexts in Android, but you can piece together a few facts from various sources.

[This blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on the official Google Android developers blog was written mostly to help address memory leaks, but provides some good information about contexts as well:

> In a regular Android application, you
>   usually have two kinds of Context,
>   Activity and Application.

Reading the article a little bit further tells about the difference between the two and when you might want to consider using the application Context (`Activity.getApplicationContext()`) rather than using the Activity context `this`).  Basically the Application context is associated with the Application and will always be the same throughout the life cycle of your app, where as the Activity context is associated with the activity and could possibly be destroyed many times as the activity is destroyed during screen orientation changes and such.

I couldn't find really anything about when to use getBaseContext() other than a post from Dianne Hackborn, one of the Google engineers working on the Android SDK:

> Don't use getBaseContext(), just use
>   the Context you have.

That was from a post on the [android-developers newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dbe5f18d3dba9aa9/fa4b981f635f16db?lnk=gst&q=getbaseContext#fa4b981f635f16db), you may want to consider asking your question there as well, because a handful of the people working on Android actual monitor that newsgroup and answer questions.

So overall it seems preferable to use the global application context when possible.

Comment: When I have an activity A which can start activity B which, in turn, can restart A with CLEAR_TOP flag (and possibly repeat this cycle many times) - what context should I use in this case in order to avoid building up a huge trail of referenced contexts? Diana says using 'this' rather than getBaseContext, but then... most of the times A will be reused but there are situations when a new object for A will be created and then the old A leaks. So it seems that getBaseContext is the most proper choice for most cases. Then it's not clear why `Don't use getBaseContext()`. Could someone clarify this?

Comment: how would one access the context object inside of a class that does not extend Activity?

Comment: @Cole, you could create a class, which we'll call "ExampleClass" here, whose constructor takes a Context object and instantiates a class instance variable, "appContext". Then, your Activity class (or any other Class for that matter) can call an ExampleClass method that makes use of the ExampleClass' "appContext" instance variable.

Answer (score 58):

Here's what I've found regarding the use of `context`:

**1) .** Within an `Activity` itself, use `this` for inflating layouts and menus, register context menus, instantiating widgets, start other activities, create new `Intent` within an `Activity`, instantiating preferences, or other methods available in an `Activity`.

**Inflate layout:**

```
View mView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myLayout, myViewGroup);
```

**Inflate menu:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Register context menu:**

```
this.registerForContextMenu(myView);
```

**Instantiate widget:**

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

**Start an `Activity`:**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
this.startActivity(mIntent);
```

**Instantiate preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
```

**2) .** For application-wide class, use `getApplicationContext()` as this context exist for the lifespan of the application.

**Retrieve the name of the current Android package:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {    
    public static String getPackageName() {
        String packageName = null;
        try {
            PackageInfo mPackageInfo = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
            packageName = mPackageInfo.packageName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // Log error here.
        }
        return packageName;
    }
}
```

**Bind an application-wide class:**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyPersistent.class);
MyServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
if (mServiceConnection != null) {
    getApplicationContext().bindService(mIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

**3) .** For Listeners and other type of Android classes (e.g. ContentObserver), use a Context substitution like:

```
mContext = this;    // Example 1
mContext = context; // Example 2
```

where `this` or `context` is the context of a class (Activity, etc).

**`Activity` context substitution:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        mContext = this;
    }
}
```

**Listener context substitution:**

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    private Context mContext;
    public MyLocationListener(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

**`ContentObserver` context substitution:**

```
public class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    private Context mContext;
    public MyContentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

**4) .** For `BroadcastReceiver` (including inlined/embedded receiver), use the receiver's own context.

**External `BroadcastReceiver`:**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            sendReceiverAction(context, true);
        }
        private static void sendReceiverAction(Context context, boolean state) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context.getClass().getName() + "." + context.getString(R.string.receiver_action));
            mIntent.putExtra("extra", state);
            context.sendBroadcast(mIntent, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Inlined/Embedded `BroadcastReceiver`:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final boolean connected = intent.getBooleanExtra(context.getString(R.string.connected), false);
            if (connected) {
                // Do something.
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**5) .** For Services, use the service's own context.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver();
    }
    private void registerReceiver() {
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        this.mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    } 
}
```

**6) .** For Toasts, generally use `getApplicationContext()`, but where possible, use the context passed from an Activity, Service, etc.

**Use context of the application:**

```
Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mToast.show();
```

**Use context passed from a source:**

```
public static void showLongToast(Context context, String message) {
    if (context != null && message != null) {
        Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

And last, don't use `getBaseContext()` as advised by Android's framework developers.

**UPDATE:** Add examples of `Context` usage.

Comment: Instead of mContext one can use `OuterClass.this` ;  see comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605459/android-why-must-use-getbasecontext-instead-of-this

Comment: +1 for such a helpful answer! I agree that the accepted answer is fine as accepted answer, but holy molly this answer was super informative! Thank you for all those examples, they helped me to better understand the context usage as a whole. I even copied your answer into a text file on my machine as a reference.

Answer (score 13):

I read this thread a few days ago, asking myself the same question. My decision after reading this was simple: always use applicationContext.

However, I encountered a problem with this, I spent a few hours to find it, and a few seconds to solve it... (changing one word...)

I am using a LayoutInflater to inflate a view containing a Spinner.

So here are two possibilities:

1)

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getApplicationContext());
```

2)

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getBaseContext());
```

Then, I am doing something like this:

```
    // managing views part
    View view = ContactViewer.mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.aViewContainingASpinner, theParentView, false);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.theSpinnerId);
    String[] myStringArray = new String[] {"sweet","love"};

    // managing adapter part
    // The context used here don't have any importance -- both work.
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getApplicationContext(), myStringArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    theParentView.addView(view);
```

What I noticed: If you instantiated your linearLayout with the applicationContext, then when you click on the spinner in your activity, you will have an uncaught exception, coming from the dalvik virtual machine (not from your code, that's why I have spent a lot of time to find where was my mistake...).

If you use the baseContext, then that's all right, the context menu will open and you will be able to choose among your choices.

**So here is my conclusion: I suppose (I have not tested it further) than the baseContext is required when dealing with contextMenu in your Activity...**

The test has been done coding with API 8, and tested on an HTC Desire, android 2.3.3.

I hope my comment have not bored you so far, and wish you all the best. Happy coding ;-)

Comment: I've always used "this" when creating views in an activity. On the basis that if the activity restarts, the views are remade and there maybe a new context which to use to make the views from again. The drawback as posted in the developer blog is whilst an ImageView is destoryed the drawable/bitmap used may hang onto that context. Nevertheless that's what I do at the moment. Regarding code elsewhere in the app (normal classes) I just use application context as its not specific to any activity or UI elements.

Answer (score 6):

First, I agree that we should use appcontext whenever possible. then "this" in activity. i've never had a need for basecontext.

In my tests, in most cases they can be interchanged. In most cases, the reason you want to get a hold of a context is to access files, preferences, database etc. These data is eventually reflected as files in your app's private data folder (/data/data/). No matter which context you use, they'll be mapped to the same folder/files so you are OK.

That's what I observed. Maybe there are cases you should distinguish them.

Comment: I've needed basecontext to globally set the app language on startup (when it does not match that of the phone default lang).

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you may use Activity context over application context when running something in a thread. When thread completes execution and you need to return the result back to the caller activity, you need that context with a handler.

```
((YourActivity) context).yourCallbackMethod(yourResultFromThread, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple words

`getApplicationContext()` as the method name suggest will make your app aware of application wide details which you can access from anywhere in the app. So you can make use of this in service binding, broadcast registration etc. `Application context` will be alive till the app exits.

`getActivity()` or `this` will make your app aware of the current screen which is visible also the app level details provided by `application context`. So whatever you want to know about the current screen like `Window` `ActionBar` `Fragementmanger` and so are available with this context. Basically and `Activity` extend `Context`. This context will alive till the current component(activity) is alive

Answer (score 0):

I've only used this and `getBaseContext` when toasting from an `onClick` (very green noob to both Java and android).  I use this when my clicker is directly in the activity and have to use `getBaseContext` in an anonymous inner clicker.  I'm guessing that is pretty much the trick with `getBaseContext`, it is perhaps returning the context of the activity in which the inner class is hiding.

Comment: This is wrong, it is returning the base context of the activity itself. To get the activity (the one you want to use as context) from an anonymous inner class use something like `MyActivity.this`. Using the base context as you describe will probably not cause problems but it is wrong.