# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I receive a crash report from my production app, which tells me that there is an NoClassDefFound Exception on one of my activity.

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
```

Where it claims that "SomeActivity" class is not found.

There is only one instance reported out of thousands of users. (On a Samsung Note Mini)
Which means it shouldn't be a compilation or wrong lib included issue.

Is there any clues for me to continue my investigation?

p/s: The activity is definitely defined in manifest. Else it won't even works on other user's phones.

Stack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sensored.SomeActivity
at com.sensored.MainActivity$2.onItemClicked(MainActivity.java:920)
at com.sensored.adapter.SomeListAdapter$2.onClick(SomeListAdapter.java:115)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3697)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820554/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-classnotfoundexception

Comment: Post stack trace for the error.

Also look ate here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880489/android-classnotfoundexception

Comment: @Sam It is just inside a regular onClickListener. The next line after this is startActivity(i)

Comment: Android's internal bug?

Comment: @Calvin have you mention SomeActivity in manifest.?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.  There is a corresponding `cause`.  NoClassDefFoundError means that there was an error when creating the class.

Comment: @JohnVint That's the stack I have from bugsense. It is from an user's phone. I can't reproduce on all my devices.

Comment: Hm, well can you post source for SomeActivity? We may be able to infer the error.  Specifically useful code is the `static{` block and any inline static fields.

Comment: The error you are seeing is usually one of two things.  1.  ClassNotFound which I have a hard time believing.  2. There was an error when the class was initialized for instance, the static block throw an uncaught exception or creating static fields threw an uncaught exception

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep all activities under same package[say com.compname.proj.views].

2) Ensure in manifest, package attribute is set to the above package[i.e com.compname.proj.views].

3) In manifest, under all activity tag, make sure android:name attribute has values matching to below pattern:

```
        android:name=".<your activity class name>"
```

Ex: android:name=".SomeActivity"

My point is not to use package name + activity class name for manifest activity declaration.

Comment: Yes. That's what exactly I did. (If I didn't it won't work on other user's phones right?)

Comment: Need not be. Usually Android system prefix project package name to activity name. In that case, if you have declared package name + activity name, under activity tag, then overall class path will not be found by system!
[You could try cleaning the project, rebuild and test new build on the device in which the crash was reported.]

Comment: The phone that report this issue is somewhere in this world which I has no access to. I need to be able to reproduce it. I try your theory with full path or without, it has no differences. Won't crash.