# Singed apk gives ClassNotFoundException in android

Tags: android

I am generating singed apk using eclipse `Export Signed Application Package.` After generating signed apk i have installed that into my device at that time I got `unfortunately stopped exception` this occurs due to `ClassNotFoundException.` This Exception occurs only with signed apk. Normal installation working fine.

My Error Log

```
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.yyy.android.xxx.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yyy.android.xxx.MyApplication
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3982)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yyy.android.xxx.MyApplication
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
05-14 18:48:39.561: E/AndroidRuntime(15982):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
```

My Manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/title_logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App" >

        <!-- Tablet Starts -->

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

I have selected check boxes `Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies` under `Order and Exports` tag. And I used `proguard.cfg` it contains `-keep public class * extends android.app.Application`. I unselected check box `Run full check when exporting` under `Lint Error Checking`. Please help me to get signed apk without any issue. Thank You.

Comment: it seems to be proguard issue..but without the logs we can't really help.

Comment: have you seen this answer? Might be related. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6282372/655987

Comment: @Alécio i have added logcat pls check it

Comment: @SathishKumar Have you tried specifying `-dontwarn` in your proguard file ?

Comment: Yeah i tried these, `-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.yyy.lib.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have this on your proguard file **-keep public class * extends android.app.Application** like this:

```
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
 -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
 -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
 -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
 -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
 -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 -keep public class * extends android.widget.BaseAdapter
 -keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
```

and make sure your **proguard file** is really *being used*.

Comment: yeah all are exists in proguard and proguard in use only

Comment: nothing strange...in this case i think there's some problem on the execution of the export of APK...check out this other post and try the various techniques that suits you best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse

Comment: Yeah sure let i try these things. Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem   after disabling   minifyEnabled true   fixed the problem. if the problem only exist on  signed apk. check buildtypes release on module.gradle

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
     // minifyEnabled true

    }
}
```