# ADT 22.6.3 does give correct signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated my eclipse ADT from version 22.6.2 to version 22.6.3. I generated signed apk using 22.6.2 and installed in device, it works fine. But after updating my ADT to version 22.6.3 and I generated signed apk and installed that in my device that installed. But when opening application it gives ClassNotFoundException. I don't know why it is happening, what is the problem. Help me to get resolve this issue. Thank You.

Comment: Please Post your error.

Comment: @GrIsHu Please check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655788/singed-apk-gives-classnotfoundexception-in-android

Comment: @GrIsHu But now i got working singed apk, what i did is, in eclipse first exported signed apk using `Export-->Export Android Application` after that is used `Andtoid Tools ---> Export Singed Android Application Package` this apk working fine. I don't know why