# Android app works on emulator, installs on phone, and crashes on device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

This is a weird and I'm not sure what I have done wrong. The app installs perfectly fine on my Samsung J7 but as soon as I move from the MainActivity to the ScheduleActivity it crashes. On the other hand my fiance who lives in the the Netherlands has a Huawei Mate 20 pro and she can use it fine. I've sent her many iterations and she just updates the app and uses it. I built this app with mvc architecture so there are no calls to the database or model. I'll include the layout, some images, and the java code. If I can add anything else please let me know. Thank you for your help solving this.

MainActvity:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button scheduleButton = findViewById(R.id.schedule_button);
            scheduleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/grade"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rest_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rest_meaning"
            android:src="@drawable/rest_logo_update"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/schedule_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/schedule_text"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rest_img"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How the main layout looks:

[image: How it looks]

Also here is a visual on the apps structure:

[image]

All I am doing is moving from the main package to the ui package and accessing the ScheduleActvity which has this code:

```
    public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
            Button mondayButton = findViewById(R.id.monday_button);
            Button tuesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.tuesday_button);
            Button wednesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.wednesday_button);
            Button thursdayButton = findViewById(R.id.thursday_button);
            Button fridayButton = findViewById(R.id.friday_button);
            Button saturdayButton = findViewById(R.id.saturday_button);
            Button sundayButton = findViewById(R.id.sunday_button);
            mondayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            tuesdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            wednesdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            thursdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            fridayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            saturdayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            sundayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.monday_button:
                    Intent monday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, MondayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(monday_intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.tuesday_button:
                    Intent tuesday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, TuesdayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(tuesday_intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.wednesday_button:
                    Intent wednesday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, WednesdayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(wednesday_intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.thursday_button:
                    Intent thursday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, ThursdayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(thursday_intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.friday_button:
                    Intent friday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, FridayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(friday_intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.saturday_button:
                    Intent saturday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, SaturdayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(saturday_intent);
                case R.id.sunday_button:
                    Intent sunday_intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, SundayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sunday_intent);
            }
        }
```

This is the respective layout file activity_schedule which has these buttons:

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/thursday_button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_state"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/monday_button" />
```

And looks like this (I so badly wish I could easily add a drop shadow to the image):
[image]

The buttons lead to a given day you want to know more about such as ThursdayActivity or MondayActvity (I'm still not sure on the ui but I'm getting closer):
[image: thrusdayactivity]
[image]
All of the daysoftheweek activities look the same as this and this ThursdayActivity:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_thursday);
            //groupsArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); --debug
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ThursdayActivity.this);
            /* Uncomment and insert the group data*/
            db.thursdayAddGroup(new Groups("Thursday","Daily reflection|Just for Today","9:00 AM","10:00 AM"));
            db.thursdayAddGroup(new Groups("Thursday","12 Step|Sponsorship","12:00 PM","1:00 PM"));
            db.thursdayAddGroup(new Groups("Thursday","HVN (Hearing voices network)","1:15 PM","2:45 PM"));
            db.thursdayAddGroup(new Groups("Thursday","WRAP","3:00 PM","4:00 PM"));
    
            TextView thursdayGroupNameOne = findViewById(R.id.thursday_group_name_one);
            TextView thursdayGroupStartTimeOne = findViewById(R.id.thursday_group_start_time_one);
            TextView thursdayGroupEndTimeOne = findViewById(R.id.thursday_group_end_time_one);
            /* Explicitly indexing the database objects */
            List<Groups> groupsList = db.getAllThursdayGroups();
            thursdayGroupNameOne.setText(groupsList.get(0).getGroupDay());
            thursdayGroupStartTimeOne.setText(groupsList.get(0).getGroupStartTime());            thursdayGroupEndTimeOne.setText(groupsList.get(0).getGroupEndTime());
```

All daysoftheweek layouts have a cardview that contain the textviews to get and display the data from the database set in the given activity such as this actvity_thursday.xml:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/grade_two">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thursday_group_name_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/group_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thursday_group_start_time_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/start_time"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thursday_group_name_one" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thursday_group_end_time_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
                    android:text="@string/end_time"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thursday_group_name_one" />

<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dash_one"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/dash"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thursday_group_end_time_one"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thursday_group_start_time_one"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thursday_group_name_one" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Got the crash log for my device:

```
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? E/Zygote: v2
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10171
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0035
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.wesleyruede.rest 
06-24 07:50:27.826 22232-22232/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-24 07:50:27.866 22232-22232/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
06-24 07:50:27.896 22232-22232/? W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.wesleyruede.restoverlayDirs =Null
06-24 07:50:27.916 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.wesleyruede.rest-1/lib/arm
06-24 07:50:27.916 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
06-24 07:50:27.936 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.wesleyruede.restoverlayDirs =Null
06-24 07:50:27.956 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-24 07:50:27.996 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-24 07:50:27.996 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-24 07:50:28.136 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:28.156 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a799c60 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
06-24 07:50:28.156 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
06-24 07:50:28.156 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-24 07:50:28.216 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.3_RB1.06.00.01.211.047_msm8937_32_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.3_RB1.06.00.01.211.047__release_AU (I88e9891e40)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.08.00.00
    Build Date: 08/09/16 Tue
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.3_RB1.06.00.01.211.047
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-24 07:50:28.226 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-24 07:50:28.266 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
06-24 07:50:28.286 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.wesleyruede.rest
06-24 07:50:28.316 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.316 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.326 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateProgramSEC
06-24 07:50:28.376 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.376 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.386 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateProgramSEC
06-24 07:50:28.406 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.406 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.416 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateProgramSEC
06-24 07:50:28.426 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateShaderSEC
06-24 07:50:28.426 22232-22253/com.wesleyruede.rest E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong call from hwui context F: ES3-glCreateProgramSEC
06-24 07:50:28.446 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@81b441d time:3489958
06-24 07:50:50.296 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-24 07:50:50.356 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-24 07:50:50.366 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.wesleyruede.rest time:3511872
06-24 07:50:50.416 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.416 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
06-24 07:50:50.426 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080068 (t=7 e=104) (error -75)
06-24 07:50:50.436 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f080068 (t=7 e=104) (error -75)
06-24 07:50:50.436 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-24 07:50:50.436 22232-22232/com.wesleyruede.rest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wesleyruede.rest, PID: 22232
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wesleyruede.rest/com.wesleyruede.rest.ui.ScheduleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3322)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.wesleyruede.rest.ui.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.wesleyruede.rest.ui.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080068
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2598)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.wesleyruede.rest.ui.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I hope this isn't too much and I did remove all unnecessary code so as not to throw the whole thing at you. Thanks truly, Wes.

Comment: Use crashlytics to see crashlogs when your app crashes after download from playstore. use logcat if you run it in debug on on android studio. In short, whithout any log information it is very hard for You to find the problem

Comment: paste your crash log. You need to understand the exception which you get on that device and to which line of code it refers to.

Comment: @GGK is crashlytics an app for your phone? I looked on the playstore and I don't see it. I'm adding my logcat right now so I hope that helps

Comment: @a_local_nobody it is useful but not the answer as each app is different. I'll try out some of the techniques mentioned in the post.

Comment: @DeadStar I've updated the post with the logcat is there a way to get it on the phone?

Comment: @WesleyRuede are you using vector image(SVG)?

Comment: crash device using which OS version?

Comment: Those logs are likely unrelated to your crash. You're looking for [the stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), which should be a large section of red lines, starting with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. You can use the filters above the log window to make it easier to find. And don't worry about Crashlytics right now. That's for crashes on end-user devices, not for your own testing.

Comment: I would investigate here `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener"`. Look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880489/android-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: To me these logs do not look like the crash cause. Connect your phone to your pc, make sure that developer options are enabled and enable debugging via USB. Then run the debug build variant on your physical device and reproduce the steps until it crashes. This time, in Logcat you gonna see the exception from the crash pointing to the lines in your code. Read the exception's details and go to the code lines to fix the issue

Comment: In `ScheduleActivity`'s layout, you have at least one `<ImageView>` with an image resource that cannot be found. That most often happens when you have that image only in a versioned folder for a version newer than you're currently running on; e.g., you have an image only in `drawable-v24/`, but you're  running on API level 23 or below.

Comment: @MikeM. this is the answer if you post it I can accept it. Thank you for your help and insight.

Comment: @RanjithKumar not to my knowledge but maybe one of the internal images is? Version 6.0.1.

Comment: Ah, good. Actually, this is a very common issue, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate, rather than repeat an answer here. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @GGK that issue they were experiencing seems different than mine.

Comment: @DeadStar thank you for explaining to me how to debug this app with a phone. Just figuring this out has made development even easier. I'll doing it this way a lot more.