# Did not work port fragments from 11 api to lower

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I was found AndroidFragment tutorial on Vogel site, and do it for Android 4.0. Then I try to port it to lower version, API 8 for example.

All time when i startmy app i have ClassNotFound Exception

Please help me to fix error.

There is my MainActivity file:

```
package com.dev.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

There is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.dev.fragments.ListFragment" ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.dev.fragments.DetailFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is my ListFragment file:

```
package com.dev.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setText(item);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", item);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
}
```

There is my DetailFragment file:

```
package com.dev.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        view.setText(item);
    }

}
```

There is my ManifestFile:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.fragments"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And there is my error:

```
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.fragments/com.dev.fragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dev.fragments.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.dev.fragments-2.apk]
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dev.fragments.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.dev.fragments-2.apk]
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-08 08:55:02.126: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: Have you added these into your Manifest file?

Comment: Yep, I add my ManifestFile above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an logcat error I guess?

I'm not trained with portation of the v4 support packages, but It seems like your MainActivity isn't deployed correctly and though not correctly put into the **com.dev.fragments-2.apk**.

Comment: Didn't really answer my question. But here you go - 

You should look up in the setting whether or not the explicit added libraries will be deployed in your project. And add the support libraries to your build path.

Comment: Yes it is logcat. And i have library.

Comment: Okay than check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965393/1548679 solution for the following issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything .

Hope this will help you out

Comment: I am do like sad here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)**

Above method used Since *API 11*

before that it was not there.

```
 :)
```