# Android application doesn't work after migration to newest ADT and android sdk

Tags: android, android-intent, adt, android-maven-plugin

I have an Android application in Eclipse Indigo with ADT version 15. Upgrading ADT to the version 21 the program crashes and is impossible to execute over both the emulator and the mobile device.

LogCat shows this error message:

```
   12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{test.hello/test.StartActivityZZ}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.start.StartActivityZZ
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.start.StartActivityZZ
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
    12-05 10:07:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(31462):    ... 11 more
```

The Android project uses maven but creating a new one without maven the problem persists and shows the same message.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: If you're using proguard when exporting the APK, ensure that you keep the Activity classes declared in the manifest.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Do you use Library project? if yes check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything/10965393#10965393) and especially Nick's comment and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At some point (probably after ver 15), the libraries you use must be placed in the "libs" folder.  Try placing a copy of your libraries there and retry