# Android app has unfortunately stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have built an android app named EverestNewsApp related to RSS Feed in order to display current news and headlines but after all I got the error the app has unfortunately stopped. Could you please have a look on the following log cat errors and notify me what I did mistake at all... thanks in advance

```
08-06 19:41:35.395: D/AndroidRuntime(23995): Shutting down VM
08-06 19:41:35.430: W/dalvikvm(23995): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a692a0)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wfwf.everestnewsapp/com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
08-06 19:41:35.430: E/AndroidRuntime(23995):    ... 11 more
08-06 19:41:35.465: I/Process(23995): Sending signal. PID: 23995 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity` - you need to make sure that `com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity` is included in your install package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything

Comment: can you please show mainfest file

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity: 
This error basically shown when
Compiler is unable to instantiate your SplashActivity.java

Make sure that you have defined your SplashActivity class in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your android manifest needs to look something like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ....

    ....
    <activity
            android:name="com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Make sure the entry is in your manifest or you'll be given the classnotfound exception

Comment: @latif mohamad Khan My mainfest file is