# Android java.lang.RuntimeException error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to build my Android plugin for Unity. But when I do, I get the follow error log in Logcat:

```
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marc/com.example.marc.CompassActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.marc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.marc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.marc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.marc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
12-11 14:45:38.745: E/AndroidRuntime(26806):    ... 11 more
```

I did a search on to why this is happening and I discovered it is because of a problem with my intent. And that I needed to add my activity to my Manifest file. However, this is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.marc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.example.marc.CompassActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

And from what I can see, my intent is there in the line `<activity android:name="com.example.marc.CompassActivity"` unless my thinking behind this is entirely wrong?

Just for completions sake, here is my java file:

```
  package com.example.marc;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Config;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;

public class CompassActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Compass";

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;

    static public float xmag;
    static public float ymag;
    static public float zmag;

    private final SensorEventListener mListener = new SensorEventListener() 
    {
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
        {
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,
        "sensorChanged (" + event.values[0] + ", " + event.values[1] + ", " + event.values[2] + ")");

            xmag = event.values[0];
            ymag = event.values[1];
            zmag = event.values[2];
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensor,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public static float getX()
    {
        return xmag;
    }

    public static float getY() 
    {
        return ymag;
    }

    public static float getZ()
    {
        return zmag;
    }
}
```

Again, as per my thinking, this is what I should be passing to my Manifest file, such, it is called "CompassActivity". Clearly though I must have done something wrong otherwise I wouldn't be getting the errors I am. Could someone please tell me what it is I am doing wrong / missing?

*edit*

Latest LogCat files:

```
   12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marc/com.example.marc.CompassActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.marc-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.marc-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.marc-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.marc-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
12-11 16:32:16.957: E/AndroidRuntime(29055):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: did you try doing a clean on the project?

Comment: I just did. However, I'm building the above as a plug in through Unity and I have eclipse open, which is how I'm getting the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.marc.CompassActivity"
```

SHOULD BE

```
   <activity android:name="CompassActivity"
```

(you already mentioned "com.example.marc" in package attribute 
The value of android:name should be name of activity class only. 
Since your manifest file says main activity class is "com.example.marc.CompassActivity", runtime environment looks for it , but it doesn't find it as your main activity class file is named as "CompassAcitvity")

[EDIT]

Main issue is that the runtime is unable to Instantiate the MainActivity because  it is not able to find the class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity" in DexPathList

See method ["findClass()" line 310-323](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore-snapshot/+/ics-mr1/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexPathList.java)

If a class is successfully found then a class object is returned other wise **null** it is returned to [BaseDexClassLoader(see line 58)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore-snapshot/+/ics-mr1/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader.java) And ClassNotFoundException is thrown in case null is received which is happening in this case.

I think either main activity class is excluded during build process or it has some different name unlike mentioned in manifest.

Comment: lol ... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm

Comment: @Selvin ....i am wrong here... I put activity name as only class name(without any period in beginning) and it has worked every time. I should have tried to replicate the error before answering.But stacktrace gave me this impression that this could be possible issue

Comment: @selvin if you see error message 
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.marc.CompassActivity""

what are your views on this?

Comment: Tried that, but I still get the same message.

Comment: @N0xus ..can you please put new stacktrace in comment

Comment: Done, with a build I literally just ran

Comment: @N0xus ok...does UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity?

Comment: @N0xus...dude please read my previous comment carefully, anyway

replace

    CompassActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity 

with

     CompassActivity extends Activity ....and see what happens

(i was going through
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything?rq=1)

Comment: @N0xus can you tell me more about class UnityPlayerActivity 
IS IT A SUBCLASS of Activity class?

Comment: I can't, all I know is that I followed a tutorial. Here is a link about Unity android extensions: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: @N0xus ...just for testing purpose can change line " CompassActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity"   to "CompassActivity extends Activity"

and see if error is still there? So we'll know if there is something wrong with UnityPlayerActivity.java.

Comment: I assure you, there is no problem with the Unity Player Activiy

Comment: I agree with you....I went through the link you mentioned  also i checked one [tutorial](http://www.platoevolved.com/blog/programming/android/creating-an-android-plugin-for-unity/)

Comment: @N0xus ...you are generating apk file?...can you give me the generated file?

Comment: I am, via Unity, and I'm sorry but I can't send the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UnityPlayerActivity` class is not found actually but Compiler shows as `CompassActivity` not found.

If you have UnityPlayerActivity in library and that is linked to you app then double check that your Project-->Right Click-->Properties-->Java Build Path--->Order and Export has your project checked.

Comment: I checked and I have my classes.jar file added which is in Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin is thwat what your meaning?

Comment: as I said in my answer please check Android Private Dependencies are checked in Order and Export.

Answer (score 0):

Following @TNR's answer - Your `UnityPlayerActivity` class is not found actually but LogCat shows as `CompassActivity` not found.

What you can try to do is:

1. Rebuild your project (just for testing) using the original UnityPlayerActivity in your manifest. is it working? (if not then fix this problem first)
2. Use JD to decompile the JAR where CompassActivity is located. Does it inherit from UnityPlayerActivity? In my case there was a problem with the compiler and it changed the inheritance to NPUnityPlayerActivity which was not found. If this problem occurs you need to recompile your code and make sure the inheritance is correct.

Good Luck!