# RuntimeException : Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

Yesterday everything worked fine with my project, but today I receive very weird errors :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.redonbas/com.example.redonbas.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.redonbas.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.redonbas-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.redonbas-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

My AndroidManifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MainActivity is in correct package:

[image]

[image]

I refered to the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074381/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist) but I copied all the File System of the project to the new, but that didn't help. I also created new project with another package and manually copied all the stuff from the old project there - the problem still remains!

What's wrong with it?

Comment: How do I get to the screen in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in past SherlockActionBar and its android-support library implementing .

Comment: So your problem was solved just by updating SherlockActionBar library ?

Comment: no, problem solved by deleting the android-support library, because it is already contains in SherlockActionBar

Comment: ohh i got it. But now a days when there are multiple support files eclipse cant able to build the project and throw "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1".

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck your `Android Dependencies` and `Android Private Libraries` Checkboxes.

Comment: I've got the Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies error

Comment: Yeah if you use this one then it will also do same!!

Comment: Can you please explain more in details ? I really tried a lot of visible ways to solve the problem, but got nothing at the moment. Maybe we can talk in skype, if you can for sure.

Comment: What do you mean  if you use this one then it will also do same!! ?