# Display Image in Listview with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, image, listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to display images in a listview with AsyncTask but I am getting an error. Saying...

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

This is error is happening on

```
public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
        this.imv = imv;
        this.path = imv.getTag().toString();
}
```

And

```
    LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = loadImage.doInBackground();
```

Here is LoadImage.java

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Yudii on 27/05/2016.
 */
class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap>{

    private ImageView imv;
    private String path;

    public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
        this.imv = imv;
        this.path = imv.getTag().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + path);

        if (file.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {


        if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
               /* The path is not same. This means that this
                  image view is handled by some other async task.
                  We don't do anything and return. */
          //  return;
        }




        if(result != null && imv != null){
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }else{
            imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is CustomList.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);


        LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = loadImage.doInBackground();


        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        return rowView;

    }
}
```

And here is MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "Google Plus",
            "Twitter",
            "Tall",
    };

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.gggggggggg,
            R.drawable.hhhhhhhhhh,
            R.drawable.ttttttttttt
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need AsyncTask? Try to use library [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and open images by one string:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + path);
Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(imageView);
```

Bitmap objects are very weight and you need to clean memory after each Bitmap image for prevent OutOfMemoryError. I recommend you to use libraries.

Comment: How exactly would I implement this?

Comment: Add `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` to your build.gradle and use it in UI thread. :)

Comment: I did that but where do I fetch the image from?

Comment: `Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(imageView);` where **file** can be File, String url or drawable resource.

Comment: I used a rawable and it says "Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;"

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831340/android-didnt-find-class-picasso-on-path-dexpathlist-failed-resolution-of)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `loadImage.execute();` instead of `Bitmap bitmap = loadImage.doInBackground();`

Comment: @YudiMoszkowski post your full java code for fill up listview

Comment: No but the images did not load into the ListView

Comment: in your AsyncTask constructor you use `this.path = imv.getTag().toString();` but where you set the tag.?

Comment: I am not sure where

Comment: so why you use it and depends on that you fetch image from `External Storage` and try to display on imageview

Comment: why you alreay use `imageId` for `Drawable` images to load image.?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your dependencies :-

```
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and then load your image :-

```
   Picasso.with(this)
                .load(drawerImage) // ImagePath
                .placeholder( R.mipmap.download)
                .error( R.mipmap.add_photo)
                .into(imageDrawerView); //ImageView
```

Comment: It says  Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;

Comment: i am not sure but this must be your targetSdkVersion .what version you are using right now???

Answer (score 0):

**1,Reason:**

As I see, in your `getView` function:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
// You need to set tag to your image view
// Ex: imageView.setTag("your_image_file_path") below this line
```

your `imageView` has no tag so the below code will get `NullPointerException`.

```
public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
    this.imv = imv;
    this.path = imv.getTag().toString(); // Crashed here.
}
```

Also, I see in your `getView` function has this code:

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

That means "your `ImageView` will set resource corresponding to defined `imageId` array". So you no need `AsyncTask` class, let remove it and change your getView like below:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        // Remove below code
        // LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(imageView);
        // Bitmap bitmap = loadImage.doInBackground();
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
```

Your `Asynctask` class is needed whenever you use path of image file, not drawable resources.

**2, Improvement:**

You can learn more about `ViewHolder pattern` when using `ListView`, `RecyclerView` to improve performance, from [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&rlz=1C1CHZL_viVN683VN683&q=viewholder%20pattern%20android&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKi_qe_fnMAhVhGaYKHSHkA6gQvwUIGigA&biw=1366&bih=653). Below is an example with your current code:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            View holder = null;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            return view;
        }
      static class ViewHolder { // should be static class
           ImageView imageView;
      }
```

Comment: That code causes the app to be very laggy and it says "Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: But, did it work? also, I suggested you improve your code with viewholder pattern.

Comment: Yeah but it is too laggy to use and I am back to the beggining, what would viewholder do?