# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/lib64]]

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Currently libraries(.so) are built using visual studio and placed on to jniLibs directory.
As shown below,

[image]

Getting below exception while finding the class in JNI call (here it is TWMainActivity but true with any other class),

```
2021-07-23 08:10:43.992 13617-1658/com.tally.twandroidconsolesimulator A/onsolesimulato: java_vm_ext.cc:578] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tally.twandroidconsolesimulator.TWMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    java_vm_ext.cc:578]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    java_vm_ext.cc:578]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    java_vm_ext.cc:578]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    java_vm_ext.cc:578] 
    java_vm_ext.cc:578]     in call to GetMethodID
```

While via global reference to the object passed via JNI call (java to C++) able to get the `jclass`.

```
   //this is working
    jclass      cls = env->GetObjectClass (sMainActivityGlobalRef);

   //this is not working throwing mentioned exceptions
  //  jclass       cls = env->FindClass ("com/tally/twandroidconsolesimulator/TWMainActivity");
```

**Note: the same code is working with Andrdoid Studio Native project without having jniLibs**

Basic code flow as follows,

```
public class TWMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("TWXPControlsGalleryApp_arm64-v8a");
    }
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);               
            InitializeMain();
        }
        public native void InitializeMain();
 }
```

//Native code

```
static void
NativeThread(JavaVM * pJavaVm, jint pJVersion, jobject pObjGblRfrnc){
    JNIEnv * env;
    auto    get_env_result = vm->GetEnv ((void **) &env, pJVersion);
    if (get_env_result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if (vm->AttachCurrentThread (env, nullptr) != JNI_OK) {
            return;
        }
    }
        jclass      cls = env->FindClass ("com/tally/twandroidconsolesimulator/TWMainActivity");

    //... rest of the code follows here
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_com_tally_twandroidconsolesimulator_TWMainActivity_InitializeMain (JNIEnv * pEnv, jobject pObj)
{
            JavaVM * sJavaVm;

        jint jv_version = pEnv->GetVersion ();
        pEnv->GetJavaVM (&sJavaVm);    
        jobject ref = pEnv->NewGlobalRef (pObj);

    std::thread thread1 (NativeThread, sJavaVm, jv_version, ref );
    thread1.detach ();
}
```

have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist),  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435658/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074381/didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path) but didn't help to rectify the problem.

Environment:

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
```

[image]

I appreciate any hint.

Comment: You haven't provided a whole lot of information. For example, which thread are you on when you call `FindClass`? Have you read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class ?

Comment: @Michael: I have updated the basic code flow. JNI call is from C++/Native thread as shown is the code

Comment: Ok, since you're on a native thread the behavior you describe is to be expected. See the page I linked to for an explanation and possible solutions.

Comment: @Michael: Sure thank you.  i'll try to load the class in `JNI_OnLoad`.

Comment: @Michael: the solution is working w.r.t loading class on JNI_OnLoad. You can add the same in answer that i'll accept it. thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindClass` will not be able to find any of your app-specific classes if invoked on a purely native thread, due to the wrong classloader being used. See [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class) in the Android developer documentation for more information.

There are various ways in which you could solve this, but the easiest is probably to resolve all classes in `JNI_OnLoad`, create global references to them, and save those global references somewhere where the rest of your code can access them.