# ClassNotFound Exception while class is declared in Manifest

Tags: android, android-afilechooser

I'm using the aFileChooser library, and every time I select to choose a file, I get a class not found error, even though I have added it to my build path and Manifest. Here's whats in mu Manifest:

```
    <activity
android:name="com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_chooser"
android:enabled="@bool/use_activity"
android:exported="true"
android:label="@string/choose_file" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And heres my logcat:

```
    08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater/com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
08-14 16:05:07.469: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything) will help?.

Comment: Thats originally how I had it set up, and tried adding it to my java build path. But I tried this again, and still had no luck. :(

Comment: can u try the correct way again, and then clean your project

Comment: [is this the one u tried?](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Comment: remove it from your build path, just do the correct-way of referencing libraries in android.

Comment: I removed it from my build path, and I have referenced the library, and just tried cleaning the project afterwards. Still no luck

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have correctly imported the library
>   Then Make Sure your actual project is not selected as library
>
> Check the Class name and file name
>   Make sure your android manifest package name is correctly mentioned

or

[NoNonsense-FilePicker](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker)

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.nononsenseapps.filepicker.FilePickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FilePickerTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I've checked all that, still nothing.