# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity" for every app I create

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException every time I create an Android application in Eclipse. This is something that has never happened before up until this morning after using Eclipse for months. It might also be worth mentioning that I installed google play services through the SDK manager this morning

Logcat:

```
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547): Process: com.example.app, PID: 27547
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-03 12:39:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(27547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
```

Manifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Comment: I think you missed to define MainActivity class in Manifest.xml file

Comment: u r not added class in mainfest file please check

Comment: check your manifest file whether you've added an entry for the activity. if yes, clean the project(Project > Clean) and run

Comment: manifest added. this is the manifest file that was generated automatically. I will clean and run now

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything

Comment: @cbrook check my answer and change your manifest, it should fix your problem

Comment: @cbrook,please check my link problem is not related Activity declaration.

Comment: ok will check link now, thank you

Comment: Yes, see Haresh's link.  You activity is being dropped on install due to an unsatisfied dependency on ActionBarActivity due to improper referencing of the support library.

Comment: I see. So it is the way I am making a reference to the appcompat library?

Comment: I have tried re-referencing like it says in the link but I am just getting errors in my code now :/

Comment: Taking out the usage of ActionBarActivity has fixed the problem so it clearly was the way that I was referencing the appcompat actionbar library. I've tried referencing using the method in the link but still no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and check if you have `com.example.app.MainActivity` :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: @BT What's different between OP's manifest and your answer?

Comment: OP might have moved the activity to different package without changing the manifest.

Comment: Still crashes I'm afraid

Comment: He use android:name=".MainActivity" instead of the full package.

Comment: @cbrook check if the activity is located in exactly same package.

Comment: @cbrook please open your MainActivity.java and see the import

Comment: @BlazeTama the .MainActivity will only concatenate to package="com.example.app".

Comment: shown at the top of MainActivity.java package com.example.app;

Comment: @Cativail do you mean its same with my answer? Sorry i dont know about that. This is strange..

Comment: @cbrook please post your project structure.

Comment: This is clearly not the right answer, don't upvote it.