# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-login

I am trying to implement faceBook Login Functionality on App . I implementing code step by step and testing it on device .

till now i havenot put any provide or activity 
I got this error after implementing code in manifest file and activity_main.xml

```
06-13 10:52:21.240  13451-13451/com.example.administrator.facebooklogin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.administrator.facebooklogin, PID: 13451
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.administrator.facebooklogin/com.example.administrator.facebooklogin.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class provider
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class provider
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018)
            at com.example.administrator.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.provider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.administrator.facebooklogin-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.administrator.facebooklogin-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:566)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:659)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:701)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018)
            at com.example.administrator.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.facebooklogin" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.aviktech.parkender.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <permission
        android:name="org.aviktech.parkender.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my String.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">FacebookLogin</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Activity ClassNotFoundException - tried everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything)

Comment: Uses-sdk should be outside application tag. Move it under manifest tag and check.

Comment: gives error ; Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] .. if i put <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" /> outside application tag

Answer (score 0):

change your manifest file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.facebooklogin" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.aviktech.parkender.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <permission
        android:name="org.aviktech.parkender.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: gives error ; Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] .. if i put <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" /> outside application tag

Answer (score 0):

It because of your application libraries got 65k dex limit. Normally android application libs have 65k dex limit. But after jelly bean release they are given support for this limit. [Check this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)(`com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0`)

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>

public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

If you are using eclips you need to download this lib and add Multi dex class in your application class.