# Trying to display a simple google map in android ..How i can do it?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display a simple google map in android.whenever I run my application,getting, unfortunately googlemap has stopped on the emulator. I have added google_play_service_lib and referred it in my project. Still I am getting same thing.
 What i can do to solve this..? 
TIA.

1. List item

This my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){

          return false;

    }
}
```

2. xml file is:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image: This is the error what I am getting in logcat.]

```
 Manifest file...
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> 
<permission
  android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    < ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,INTERNET,
     ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,READ_GSERVICE
       These all permission I have added>
 <uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
               />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="APIkey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>
   </manifest>
```

Comment: Edit : xml file is <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: please show your manifest.

Comment: Have you declared your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes..and added all permissions ..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything

Comment: I have added(referred) google_play_service_lib library in to my project.But still the same error..

Comment: You can try to clone my repo [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-basic-android), it will show the basic map for you. Also please follow steps [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE&index=8&list=WL) to learn.

Comment: ok..thank u.. @bjiang