# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after Android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I updated to Android Studio 2.1 from the stable channel. As soon as I did that I am getting ClassNotFoundException to my login class, which is declared in the manifest for long time. Prior to the update my app was compiling fine.

```
com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 29605
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.Login}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.Login" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.Login" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.Login
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is my gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//    compile files('libs/smack-core-4.0.7.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

So far I have tried
1)Clean and rebuild project
2)Delete the build folder and rebuild project/restart Android Studio
3)Switch to canary channel as well as dev channel and update
4)Check and uncheck the offline mode in Settings
Obviously this is a bug, but is there a solution to this? How can I reverse the recent updates? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion '23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: did you update the com.android.tools.build:gradle version after upgrading to Android Studio 2.1 ?

Comment: Have you try to disable instant run and run your project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

Clear app `cache`

Clear app `data`

`Uninstall` app

`Run/Debug` again

Hope it works!

Answer (score 6):

We are experiencing a similar error after updating to version 2.1 of Android Studio. A class added long ago is now not being found on application start. It's **only happening with Android 5.1 and 5.1.1**. Really weird crash!

The solution to this was enabling "**Instant Run**" solves the issue on Lollipop.

Comment: In my case it was also "Instant Run" related, but I had to disable it to get it running again. After the first successful run, I enabled "Instant Run" again and it worked.

Comment: @Ferran Pons: I have the same problem with Lollipop devices, turning Instant Run on worked for me, but I don't want to use Instant Run, anyway to disable it without problem?

Comment: @LêTháiPhúcQuang AFAIK the only option is to use a different device with a higher API. Sorry for replying so late.

Comment: @FerranPons hi there, it has been while since my last comment, i've just take a look and the problem has gone without Instant Run enabled. But I have no idea when did I turn off Instant Run.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this error and had looked at a number of SO threads, and various resources and also checked in to the android dev irc. The answers seem to follow a trend:

### Gradle/Android Studio General:

Clean build, reset Android Studio caches, uninstall/reinstall android studio, leave Android Studio and come back to it in 2 hours, restart your computer.

### Referencing the class

Is it correctly listed through the manifest? What about gradle configuration?

### Loading Classes via IDE (though that seems mostly eclipse related)

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

[Android Activity ClassNotFoundException - tried everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vqcGhEPHdo

### My solution: naming conflict?

I found through pure desperation that by changing my class name `Manifest` to `MyCoolManifest` or something like that, I no longer had the issue. Since your class name is `Login`, perhaps renaming the class will solve your problem.

Comment: I had the same issue on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6. I changed the class name of the activity, ran it and it worked (I just changed the class name back afterwards). Strange issue, I wonder what could've caused it.

Comment: What is the reason for waiting two hours?

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning gradle cache & build by running each line in the terminal:

```
gradlew --stop
gradlew cleanBuildCache
gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide:

```
compileSdkVersion '22' buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

as your `targetSdkVersion 22`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go : Clean the project , And uninstall the existing app and run Again .

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing of the above worked. Until I disabled "**Instant Run**" to Hot Swap code.

Android studio version: **2.3.3** Latest (*at the date of the answer*)

Android Test Devices: **5.1.1, 6.0.1**

To disable **instant run**. In Android studio, Got to Preferences -> write "**Instant Run**" in the search bar -> Uncheck "**Enable Instant Run to hot swap code ...**"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing lambda with anonymous class:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException happened in my android studio project in two classes – in both of them there was lambda expressions. After I replaced lambda with anonymous class – the build was successful.