# Android Wear ClassNotFoundException after gradle update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os, classnotfoundexception, gradlew

After updating the project gradle wrapper from 2.14.1 to 3.3 and Android gradle plugin from 2.2.3 to 2.3.1 I have a ClassNotFoundException on the wearable application start.

Notes:

- If the wearable app pushed directly from the Android Studio to the watch, and not as the part of the mobile release APK, everything works ok.
- On the previous gradle version no exceptions.

Exception:

> 04-12 15:54:57.824 18000-18000/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.artyom.aa.artyom.android, PID: 18000
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.artyom.aa.artyom.android.MyWearApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.artyom.aa.artyom.android.MyWearApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.artyom.aa.artyom.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.artyom.aa.artyom.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4685)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.artyom.aa.artyom.android.MyWearApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.artyom.aa.artyom.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.artyom.aa.artyom.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
>                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4685) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.artyom.aa.artyom.android.MyWearApplication
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                               ... 12 more
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Wearable build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

def serverVersion = project.file("../server_version.txt").text

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.artyom.aa.artyom.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(project.ext.releaseStoreFile)
            storePassword project.ext.releaseStorePassword
            keyAlias project.ext.releaseKeyAlias
            keyPassword project.ext.releaseKeyPassword
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file(project.ext.debugStoreFile)
            storePassword project.ext.debugStorePassword
            keyAlias project.ext.debugKeyAlias
            keyPassword project.ext.debugKeyPassword
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            //TODO should be removed in production
            multiDexEnabled true
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.1'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'

    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile project(':shared')
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.shahar2k5:androidutils:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Rx import
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'

    compile("com.artyom.aa:smoove-mobile-dto_2.11:$serverVersion") {
        transitive = false //do not bring dependant jars
        changing = true
    }
    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveMobileLogicLayer:$serverVersion") {
        transitive = false //do not bring dependant jars
        changing = true
    }
    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveDataModel:$serverVersion") {
        changing = true
    }
    compile 'com.artyom.aa:SmooveLogging:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
        // workaround issue #73
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
}
```

Application build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

def buildVersion = project.file("../version.txt").text
def serverVersion = project.file("../server_version.txt").text


android {
    project.group = 'com.artyom.aa'
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.artyom.aa.artyom.android"
        buildConfigField 'String', "PEBBLE_APP_UUID", project.ext.pebbleAppUUID
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 70
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName buildVersion
        multiDexKeepProguard file("proguard-rules.pro")
        ndk {
            moduleName "accelerometer_ndk"
            // This is the name of the module as defined in jni/Android.mk
            cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK -D_DEBUG" // Define some macros
            ldLibs "log", "android"  //load .so files from ndk's usr\lib
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(project.ext.releaseStoreFile)
            storePassword project.ext.releaseStorePassword
            keyAlias project.ext.releaseKeyAlias
            keyPassword project.ext.releaseKeyPassword
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file(project.ext.debugStoreFile)
            storePassword project.ext.debugStorePassword
            keyAlias project.ext.debugKeyAlias
            keyPassword project.ext.debugKeyPassword
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', "REPORT_CRASHES", 'true'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            output.outputFile.parent,
                            "artyom.apk")
                }
            }
        }

        debug {
            ndk {
                debuggable = true
            }
            versionNameSuffix "_DEV"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', "REPORT_CRASHES", 'false'
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            output.outputFile.parent,
                            "artyom.apk")

                }
            }
        }

        daily {
            versionNameSuffix "_" + getDate()
            debuggable true //TODO should be removed in production
            buildConfigField 'boolean', "REPORT_CRASHES", 'true'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            output.outputFile.parent,
                            "artyom.apk")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java/']
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 1
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
}


dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    //Validation dependencies
    //Dependency Injection
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    //Logging decencies


    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveAnalyticsCore:$serverVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'log4j'
        changing = true
    }
    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveAndroidImpl:$serverVersion") {
        exclude module: 'SmooveDataModel'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'log4j'
        changing = true
    }

    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveDataModel:$serverVersion") {
        transitive = false //do not bring dependant jars
        changing = true
    }

    /* TODO: Remove the below jackson dependencies when data model will be in separate jar*/
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }
    //Build fix workaround - http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/pom-dependency-excludes-wildcard-excluding-the-dependency-itself

    //Caused by Robolectric dependency
    compile('org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3') {
        transitive = false;
    }

    // Android Wear dependencies
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':shared')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.shahar2k5:androidutils:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.getpebble:pebblekit:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6'
    compile("com.artyom.aa:SmooveLogging:$serverVersion") { changing = true }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
}

//tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
//    if (task.name in ['assembleRelease', 'assembleDaily']) {
//        task.dependsOn 'test'
//    }
//}

def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm')
    return formattedDate
}
```

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: Did it many times

Comment: Did you try the solution in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881299/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-android-studio-update) where you Clear app cache, Clear app data , Uninstall app then Run/Debug again?

Comment: @noogui Yes, I did it.