# app crashes while trying to lunch it on second profile

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

hi i`m trying to lunch my app on a restricted account but it keeps crashing at startup. so i installed it on second account and got the log for it.

```
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.persian.zarareader, PID: 11690
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.persian.zarareader/com.persian.zarareader.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.persian.zarareader.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.persian.zarareader-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.persian.zarareader-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.persian.zarareader.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.persian.zarareader-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.persian.zarareader-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2467)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.persian.zarareader.MainActivity
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:                ... 12 more
01-07 14:16:29.357 11690 11690 E AndroidRuntime:        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

the app is working fine on main user but i need to make it work in a restricted one. so far nothing worked!
android version is 5 and any help would be much appreciated

Comment: have you applied proguard for app ?

Comment: this was default in graddle buildtools:     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your APK not build Proper that why get crash and error.
First you clean your project and then Build APK.
install in device After complete build APK Process.

Comment: thanks. going to teat it but why is it only working in main profile/user?

Comment: Please add your MainActivity in your  AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: sorry for the delay

Comment: Please refer this Answer might be work [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything?rq=1]