# java.lang.classnotfound exception is coming while launching a simple helloworld app on mi4i android phone

Tags: android

java.lang.classnotfound exception is coming, while launching a simple helloworld app on mi4i android phone. it is running fine on Emulator. I am using android studio 2.3. I already checked the class name and path in mainfest file. Can anybody help, what wrong i am doing? Following is the error screenshot [Mobile screenshot while launching app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxN8V.png)

Following is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tarun.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check logcat and/or launch the app in debug mode to see where it is dying.

Comment: See you build.gradle file.. and check your minsdk and targetsdk version

minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: I am running on my phone...while launching it is throwing this error. it is running fine on emulator. I am building it using android studio 2.3.

Comment: Print your logcat here.

Comment: @Azhar, i checked it is same

Comment: Try to clean and build it again.

Comment: post logCAT as well as manifest file please!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="x.app1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="Hello">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: LOGCAT 
03-11 15:49:43.590 2430-2430/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-11 15:49:43.590 2430-2430/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-11 15:49:43.803 2430-2430/x.app1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/x.app1-1/lib/x86
03-11 15:49:43.808 2430-2430/x.app1 I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for x.app1

Comment: 03-11 15:49:44.196 2430-2430/x.app1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-11 15:49:44.517 2430-2551/x.app1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-11 15:49:44.517 2430-2551/x.app1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1

Comment: 03-11 15:49:44.554 2430-2551/x.app1 E/EGL_emulation: tid 2551: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
03-11 15:49:44.554 2430-2551/x.app1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa9e771c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
03-11 15:49:44.589 2430-2430/x.app1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

Comment: not able to post all at once so posted in split way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, can you please check the screenshot attached on this link -https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxN8V.png

Comment: You should edit your question with the stacktrace as text, not a screenshot or a comment.

Comment: It is difficult to type word by word the stack trace..how can i convert into text

Comment: First of all, copy your comments above directly into your question. Secondly, how are you running your app? Are you using Android Studio? If so, you should open the Android Monitor window and copy the stacktrace from there.

Comment: I am not running it on android studio...i am running it on mobile phone.

Comment: Yes please. It is better to discuss this on chat. thanks

Comment: The solution for this issue is answered for eclipse but not for android studio in the below thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything