# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory when using Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-appcompat

When I try to run my app and load te map from Google to show nearby places, it will show the map but not the places. I have been searching on Stackoverflow but haven't found a solution that works...

this is part of my error :

```
2018-12-07 23:59:28.409 1872-1872/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2018-12-07 23:59:30.224 1714-1849/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-07 23:59:30.309 1714-1849/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-07 23:59:30.496 6272-6388/? E/PlaceInferenceEngine: Position timestamp out of order. Previous: 1544223082635, Current: 1544219970000. Skipping this Position.
2018-12-07 23:59:40.591 1872-1885/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-07 23:59:50.218 1822-1822/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2018-12-07 23:59:50.218 1822-1822/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2018-12-07 23:59:50.643 1872-1885/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-07 23:59:58.282 1727-1812/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2018-12-08 00:00:00.716 9163-9163/? E/ndroid.calenda: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2018-12-08 00:00:00.916 9180-9180/? E/viders.calenda: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2018-12-08 00:00:00.949 9163-9163/? E/PrefServiceImpl: Primary account is null
2018-12-08 00:00:21.270 1872-1885/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

my manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.rhaniegghe.googlemaps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />


    </application>


</manifest>
```

and my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rhaniegghe.googlemaps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right directions. I have tried the following solution but without luck.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything?rq=1)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to use *Invalidate cache and restart*.

Click File in Menu option of Android Studio and search for option *Invalidate cache and restart*.

Comment: I don't know why but this solved it for me... Thanks!