# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.blogapp.whateverString"

Tags: android, manifest, androidx

After i migrate androidx it show to me when i click the button 
why this happend?

What i want to do when i click the button open the calendar

**This is my error when i clickthe button**

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.blogapp.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.blogapp-BjDX
```

**This is my Manifest.xml that where's whateverString came form**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.together">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <!-- 맵 이용하기 위함 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- 다음 지도 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- 대략적인 위치 참조 권한 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <!-- 정확한 위치 참조 권한 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

I use this two lines

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Because i was added implements these below

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.1'
```

i was saw from here someone recommend when occuring error in mycase, using these below code

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

so That's the reason why i use "WhateverString"

How can i solve that problem? 
i don't understand why suddenly show to me error that after i migrate androidx

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965393/5773044

Comment: I am facing same error? did you manage to solve this ? Please tell me

Answer (score 3):

In the  manifest file you added this line

```
 android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

but the class can not find "whateverString" so you have to  remove

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

add these lines to the manifest file

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="p"
```