# Register BroadcastReceiver to Widget (Difference of Context object)

Tags: android, android-widget

A have a little confuse the **difference** between **Widget Context** and **Application Context**:
Regarding problem relate with **unable** to register new BroadcastReceiver via implement source code of Android Widget (Ref.1)

---

For readability reason, i copy my answer as below:
★**Problem by Henry (Ref.1):**

> I am making a widget that needs a
>   broadcast receiver, like the one in
>   com.example.android.apis.appwidget.ExampleBroadcastReceiver.
>   However, the example defines
>   Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED in the
>   manifest, but there are some that do
>   not allow this
>
> For example, Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK
>   says "You can not receive this through
>   components declared in manifests, only
>   by exlicitly registering for it with
>   Context.registerReceiver(). "
>
> So I removed the manifest declarations
>   and tried replacing the
>   AppWidgetProvider.onEnabled function
>   that was in the example with a call
>   like the following:
>   context.registerReceiver(myReceiver,
>   new
>   IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
>
> (where "myReceiver" is an instance of
>   the receiver I want.)  However, when I
>   try to run the code, I get the
>   following error:
>
> Unable to start
>   receiver...android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException:
>   IntentReceiver components are not
>   allowed to register to receive intents

**★Our analysis this issue and solution for this problem (Ref.1)**

> This is result after investigate this
>   problem, i was handler successful this
>   issue. So i collect as report to share
>   with android developer. Hope it help
>
> Here is result:
>
> ❶ISSUE:* 
>   Regarding limited from Widget, when try to register
>   BroadcastReceiver via explicit source
>   code: (No effect when register
>   BroadcastReceiver via Manifest.xml)
>
> ❷EXAMPLE: * 
>   BroadcastReceiver: ACTION_TIME_TICK message is one
>   example: As docs from Android had
>   point out: "You can not receive this
>   through components declared in
>   manifests, only by exlicitly
>   registering for it with
>   Context.registerReceiver()." (Ref.1)
>
> ❸PREVIOUS SOLUTION:* Code Snippet: context.registerReceiver(this,
>   intentName); (1)
>
> ❹ERROR when used 3★ solution* When implement follow (1), it though
>   exception:
>   android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException:
>   IntentReceiver components are not
>   allowed to register to receive intents
>
> ★Good news for anyone who need to
>   register BroadcastReceiver in Widget
>   :) we CAN register successful
>   BroadcastReceiver
>
> ❺OUR SOLUTION:* But, We can fixed this by used application context
>   instead of Widget context(*) Code
>   Snippet:
>   context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(this,
>   intentName);
>
> ❻REFERENCE:* http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#AC...
>   Regarding
>
> ❼TARGET ENVIRONEMNT:* SDK 2.3, both on Emulator and NexusOne 2.3, If
>   anyone success with this solution
>   please update our report
>
> ❽NOTES* May be difference between Context object of widget and
>   application, but i still don't known
>   exactly cause of this problem.
>
> Please let me known if your have
>   better solution or explain more
>   clearly
>
> Also i had solver this problem, but i
>   still don't known exactly cause of
>   this problem.
>
> Please let me known if your have
>   better solution or explain more
>   clearly

---

**★CONCLUTION:**

● **NG**: When use **Widget context** to register BroadcastReceiver

```
context.registerReceiver(this, intentName);
```

-> it thought **exception:**

```
Unable to start receiver...android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
```

● **OK**: When use **Application context** everything working fine:

```
ontext.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(this, intentName);
```

---

**★QUESTION:**
Also our solution can solver problem: "unable to register new broadcast message via implement source code of Android widget".

**But i still concern two Qestion:**

**Question**❶: The difference between Widget Context and Application Context and other Context object (Activity Context)'

**Question**❷: Because context object was use usually so when to use Application context and when to use other Context.

For ❷ i had found explain relate with memory leak (Ref. 2), but i think it may not enough (Ref.2)

So if your have answer please let me known, any answer appreciated.

Thanks

---

**★Referecens:**

(1) http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/790da1a655f4a227/0b8d6aad1dc2d371?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Broadcast+Receiver+From+Widget#0b8d6aad1dc2d371

(2) http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: You really need to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and reprase / cleanup / simplify your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is over a year old and is definitely long and complicated and the English language is difficult to understand. However, it still probably deserves some kind of answer.

If I understand, you are basically asking for the difference between the different Android `Context` objects. The main difference is **scope** or **lifetime**.

The application's Context (that you can get with `Activity.getApplicationContext()` or `Context.getApplicationContext()` has a lifetime of your entire application. The application Context is created when your application (or parts of it) are started. It lives (more or less) forever.

An activity's Context is created when that Activity is created and goes away when that activity is destroyed. If you are doing anything with the UI, you need to do that using the activity's Context so that when the activity is destroyed, those things that are related to that activity are also cleaned up.

There are other Contexts like the one you get in a BroadcastReceiver or an AppWidgetProvider in `onReceive()`. This Context has a very short lifetime (it is destroyed immediately after the `onReceive()` method returns). Therefore you can only do limited things with this Context.

You want to register a Receiver to listen for the broadcast Intents you are interested in. You cannot do this with the Context you get in `onReceive()` because that Context has a short lifetime and the listener has to be linked to something. In this case you can use the application's Context to link the listener to. This works, but you need to realize that you've created some objects that will never go away because they are always active. At least you should make sure that you clean this up when the user deletes your widget from his home screen by removing the listener using `unregisterReceiver()`.

There are a lot of questions/answers on StackOverflow regarding usage of `Context`. For example, [What's the difference between the various methods to get a Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context)

Comment: +1. The short version: If you get the error `IntentReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents` in a BroadcastReceiver, and you are using the `context` parameter from OnReceive to build a new Intent, ie. `new Intent(context,..)`, then change it to `context.getApplicationContext()...`. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Even though David Wesser provided an excellent answer, I think there are still relevant information to be added. So here it goes:

In the end, **Context** is just a reference to different components of your own app (like resources, package information, etc) and to the operating system outside it. So all different contexts you mentioned are just a reference to the same thing, the only difference is for how long each reference is valid.

In the specific case of **AppWidgetProvider**, the context you get on its methods is the same context provided by **BroadcastReceiver** onReceive method. Actually **AppWidgetProvider** is just a fancy name for a regular **BroadcastReceiver** which calls specific methods when receiving widget related intents, like **ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE**.

The problem with your code is that **AppWidgetProvider** has a very short lifecycle: every time a widget broadcast arrives, a new instance of *AppWidgetProvider* is created just to execute the correspondent method. So when you do this:

```
context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(this, intentName);
```

you are registering a new **BroadcastReceiver** to your app context every time a widget intent is received. Besides that, when you try to unregister your **AppWidgetProvider**, you are actually referring to another instance of it, so you will probably get an exception and even if you catch it, there will be a memory leak on your app.

So if you need to programmatically add intent filters to a **BroadcastReceiver** here is my suggestion:

1)Create a different **BroadcastReceiver** on a long lived context class, like a class that extends Application. Lets call it **mMainReceiver**.

2)Apply the intent filter programatically on it, and register and unregister it according to your needs.

3)Create a private intent, like **MY_ACTION_TIME_TICKER** and fires it from your **mMainReceiver** onReceive method.

4)On your manifest, register a **MY_ACTION_TIME_TICKER** filter to your AppWidgetProvider receiver.

This way you can have a single BroadcastReceiver acting as a bridge to your AppWidgetProvider, and you can register and unregister it anytime.

Comment: "Create a different BroadcastReceiver on a long lived context class, like a class that extends Application." How to do it? Is there a long lived class in widget?