# Android Widget Failing To Update

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, updates, android-appwidget

I'm making a widget and i know some of my code such as the broadcastReceiver is wrong at the moment but it wont even update to hardcoded `setTextViewText`.

My problem is I've no idea why this happens and my widget just wont update.

Here's my code i hope someone can figure out where ive gone wrong:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

RemoteViews views;

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];


        IntentFilter batteryLevelFliter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        context.registerReceiver(batteryChangedReceiver, batteryLevelFliter);

        String alarm = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAlarm, alarm);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNextAlarm, "qwertyuiop");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int rawLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int level = -1;
        if (rawLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
            level = (rawLevel * 100) / scale;
        }
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean charging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
        if (charging) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvBattery, "Charging: " + level + "%");
            if (level == 100) {
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvBattery, "Battery Full");
            }
        } else {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvBattery, "Battery: " + level + "%");
        }
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver, so you cannot register new BroadcastReceiver to the your AppWidget's context. In your code, you will not receive battery event from your BroadcastReceiver. Refer these previous questions. :)

[Android Broadcast Receiver in Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181847/android-broadcast-receiver-in-widget)

[Register BroadcastReceiver to Widget (Difference of Context object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112529/register-broadcastreceiver-to-widget-difference-of-context-object?answertab=oldest#tab-top)