# PendingIntent not opening Activity in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

In my `Service`, I open up a notification on normal run, using this code:

```
private final static NOTIFICATION_ID = 412434;
private void startNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
    builder.setContentTitle("Running");

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);

    notification = builder.build();

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

The `PendingIntent` is to open the `MainActivity` when the Notification is tapped. This works perfectly fine on all my test devices, using Android 2.3.3, 2.3.5 and Android 4.1.

It does not work, however on my Nexus 7 (Android 4.3), this doesn't work at all. Nothing happens when I tap on the Notification.

Did something change in the way these are put together that I missed?

Comment: It looks OK. Anything unusual about `MainActivity`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Not that I am aware of, it implements `onNewIntent`, but that one only looks for an action that is not used by the notification.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue recently. I resolved it by providing a non 0 value to the `PendingIntent.getActivity` requestCode parameter.

Comment: @markushi_ Can you make that an answer so I can check it as such?

Comment: same problem on Android 4.4

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There seems to be an issue on some 4.3 devices. It can be resolved by providing a non 0 value to the `requestCode` parameter.

Example:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: In my experience with this issue, I had to set the request code to be higher than 1000 to ensure the PendingIntent worked on the Nexus 10 running 4.3. So something like `REQUEST_CODE_BASE + myRequestCode` where `const REQUEST_CODE_BASE = 1000` seems to fix the issue on all devices I've tested.

Comment: It was working with 0 then stopped one day switched to requestcode=1000 it works. Thx. Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2

Comment: +1 excellent, was having issues with this on HTC One 4.4. RQ 1 fixed for me

Comment: thank you . I have been fighting with this for the last hour or two. thanks. For what it's worth I think this is an issue for > 4.3

Comment: I put this line yesterday, and works correctly but now not work, I have the same code (works rarely why ?)

Comment: @delive are you sure that you don't have two notifications with the same `requestCode`? I faced it so I use a unique notification id for each notification.

Comment: I solved my problem. with a miliseconds id, but thanks.

Comment: @delive I think it is the same as what I did. Just see that two subsequent notifications don't have the same `requestCode`s.

Answer (score 2):

That's worked for me:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, randomInt, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: THIS was what worked for me when having multiple notifications for the same app. Thank you!