# Notification action with pending intent not working on JellyBean+

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I've implemented a push notification with a pending intent so when the user clicks the notifications it opens a screen with details.

It's working fine on all devices HTC .. Samsung S2, S3, ACE and ACE+

But for some reason it's not working S4 or S5 .. anybody had this problem ?

I'm using the NotificationCompact class

Comment: What is your error.  I use the NotificationnCompat class - it works fine on Samsung devices.  Please put your logcat here.

Comment: Not error, when you click on it nothing happens, the notification bar is collapsed up and instead of opening my activity, nothing happens

Comment: I am confident there is an error, double check your logcat. I will reiterate that this is likely NOT a device compatibility issue, but something wrong with YOUR code.

Comment: There is no log when i click on the notification ..

Comment: Found the answer thanks to that [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031861/pendingintent-not-opening-activity-in-android-4-3

Comment: Changing the requestCode in the pendingIntent has helped me.  Got this help from the answer of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19166954/1637525

Comment: @MarkaA, see my above comment :), but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 4):

Set `requestCode` on `PendingIntent` to non-zero value.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 42, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//                              ^^ THIS
```