# Can someone clarify Android context references?

Tags: android, this, android-context

My misunderstanding continues ...

Can anyone cite references for the proper use of `get*Context()`? I get conflicting recommendations about using `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()` and `getContext()` and my understanding is that using `this` is a convenience to `get*Context()`. I would like to study more specifically of what Dalvik is intending its object and access methods.

I had code reviews that changed my calls to `getBaseContext()` to `getApplicationContext()`, now I am seeing suggestions to use this.

Comment: Try to read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Read this article. It describe why we should use `getApplicationContext()` rather than Activity's `this`

This is summary of the article:

In summary, to avoid context-related memory leaks, remember the following:

- Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)
- Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity

Comment: don't forget they are all a little different.  getContext() gets the CURRENT context, BaseContext() is usually the originating parent context.  ApplicationContext is guaranteed to not have be fuddled with because it is associated with the application and not with any activity in particular.