# Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"

Tags: android, this, android-context

What is the difference between `getContext()` , `getApplicationContext()` , `getBaseContext()` , and "`this`"?

Though this is simple question I am unable to understand the basic difference between them. Please give some easy examples if possible.

Comment: There is an excellent writeup in the first answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the various methods to get a Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context)

Answer (score 604, accepted):

- [`View.getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29):  Returns the context the view is currently running in.  Usually the currently active Activity.
- [`Activity.getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29):  Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside
  of).  Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a
  context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the
  current Activity.
- [`ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29):  If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper.  The
  Context referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via
  getBaseContext().

Comment: +CooL i3oY same with getContext

Comment: actually i am confuse that what is the proper defination of context??

Comment: "this" and getContext() both are same

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. I would give this another update (if I could) if i contained a real life example of each of the `Context`s so that the forum and I can get a clearer understanding of how they're used.

And maybe what object requires which of the `Context`s.

Comment: What if you get your Application extented class?

Comment: You said about "Usually the currently active Activity.", what it could be in other cases if not currently active Activity? Thx

Comment: `this` and `getContext()` are not always same e.g. in Activity class, you can use `this` because `Activity` inherits from `Context` but method `getContext()` is not in `Activity` class. @mikedroid @KCRaju

Comment: `this` gives an instance of the class it's in, which could be any class, not necessarily a context. If you use it in an Activity class, then `this` will be an instance of a `Context`.

Comment: You can not use `this` in an inner class of an `Activity`, but you can use `getContext()`.

Comment: Pls incorporate letter A and B into your definition of context withhin context, it's not clear in any answer which context is accessed.

Comment: This might be Java syntax help to some: `YourActivity.this.getApplicationContext()` will qualify your context from instance of `YourActivity`. Otherwise above answer is great - it is all about the lifecycle of code you are writing - out living the activity/fragment or not.

Comment: To understand first point **view.getContext()** better refer **[this](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2009/12/context.html)**.

Comment: `getBaseContext()` needs more explaination perhaps with an example.

Comment: @nandan you said "getContext() is not in Activity class" what do you mean by that ? I thought we are able to use getContext() in Activity class ?

Comment: @isJulian00
Activity is a subclass of Context. "context.getContext" would make much sense. "this" already IS the context in Activity.

Comment: so for example basecontext would be like for example a state of a button within a view? correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 154):

Most answers already cover `getContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` but **getBaseContext()** is rarely explained.

The method `getBaseContext()` is only relevant when you have a `ContextWrapper`.
Android provides a `ContextWrapper` class that is created around an existing `Context` using:

```
ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
```

The benefit of using a `ContextWrapper` is that it lets you “modify behavior without changing the original Context”. For example, if you have an activity called `myActivity` then can create a `View` with a different theme than `myActivity`:

```
ContextWrapper customTheme = new ContextWrapper(myActivity) {
  @Override
  public Resources.Theme getTheme() { 
    return someTheme;
  }
}
View myView = new MyView(customTheme);
```

`ContextWrapper` is really powerful because it lets you override most functions provided by `Context` including code to access resources (e.g. `openFileInput()`, `getString()`), interact with other components (e.g. `sendBroadcast()`, `registerReceiver()`), requests permissions (e.g. `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()`) and resolving file system locations (e.g. `getFilesDir()`). `ContextWrapper` is really useful to work around device/version specific problems or to apply one-off customizations to components such as Views that require a context.

The method **getBaseContext()** can be used to access the “base” Context that the `ContextWrapper` wraps around. You might need to access the “base” context if you need to, for example, check whether it’s a `Service`, `Activity` or `Application`:

```
public class CustomToast {
  public void makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration) {
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
      context = context.baseContext();
    }
    if (context instanceof Service)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Cannot call this from a service");
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Or if you need to call the “unwrapped” version of a method:

```
class MyCustomWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
  @Override
  public Drawable getWallpaper() {
    if (BuildInfo.DEBUG) {
      return mDebugBackground;
    } else {
      return getBaseContext().getWallpaper();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say, this is the most important answer after an accepted one.

Comment: I would say that the existence of `ContextWrapper` is one of the worst decisions ever made by developers of Android framework. When they realized that they created an entire family of God Objects, instead of doing the right thing and refactoring the code toward Single Responsibility, they added an ugly hack that allowed to change Context behavior by deepening the inheritance tree. Bad software engineering at its ugliest.
As for us, developers, IMHO no one should ever use `getBaseContext()` or `ContextWrapper`. If you do - it is a huge "code smell".

Comment: I'd like to see the complete `CustomToast` code. ＴＨＡＮＫＳ：）））

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was not aware that ContextWrapper was to be used like this!! I always thought it was something internal from the Android Team. In my sense, this is the expected Answer. T H A N K S !!!

Answer (score 47):

The question "what is Context" is one of the most difficult questions in the Android universe.

Context defines methods that access system resources, retrieve application's static assets, check permissions, perform UI manipulations and many more. In essence, `Context` is an example of God Object anti-pattern in production.

When it comes to which kind of `Context` should we use, it becomes very complicated because except for being God Object, the hierarchy tree of `Context` subclasses violates Liskov Substitution Principle brutally.

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329210012/https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) (now from Wayback Machine) attempts to summarize `Context` classes applicability in different situations.

Let me copy the main table from that post for completeness:

> ```
> +----------------------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
> |                            | Application | Activity | Service | ContentProvider | BroadcastReceiver |
> +----------------------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
> | Show a Dialog              | NO          | YES      | NO      | NO              | NO                |
> | Start an Activity          | NO¹         | YES      | NO¹     | NO¹             | NO¹               |
> | Layout Inflation           | NO²         | YES      | NO²     | NO²             | NO²               |
> | Start a Service            | YES         | YES      | YES     | YES             | YES               |
> | Bind to a Service          | YES         | YES      | YES     | YES             | NO                |
> | Send a Broadcast           | YES         | YES      | YES     | YES             | YES               |
> | Register BroadcastReceiver | YES         | YES      | YES     | YES             | NO³               |
> | Load Resource Values       | YES         | YES      | YES     | YES             | YES               |
> +----------------------------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+
> ```
>
> 1. An application CAN start an Activity from here, but it requires that a new task be created.  This may fit specific use cases, but can create non-standard back stack behaviors in your application and is generally not recommended or considered good practice.
> 2. This is legal, but inflation will be done with the default theme for the system on which you are running, not what’s defined in your application.
> 3. Allowed if the receiver is null, which is used for obtaining the current value of a sticky broadcast, on Android 4.2 and above.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 40):

> **getApplicationContext()** - Returns the context for all activities running in application.
>
> **getBaseContext()** -  If you want to access Context from another context within application you can access.
>
> **getContext()** - Returns the context view only current running activity.

Answer (score 28):

`Context` provides information about the `Actvity` or `Application` to newly created components.

Relevant `Context` should be provided to newly created components (whether application context or activity context)

Since `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, one can use `this` to get that activity's context

Answer (score 3):

**getApplicationContext()**

> this is used for application level and refer to all activities.

**getContext() and getBaseContext()**

> is most probably same .these are reffered only current activity which is live.

**this**

> is  refer current class object always.

Answer (score 2):

this: current class object

getContext(): return context for current live activity

getApplicationContext(): return all activities which are running in application

Answer (score 2):

**getApplicationContext()** - it's Returns the context for all activities running in application.

**getBaseContext()** - when you want to access Context from another context within application you can access.

**getContext()** - it's Returns the context view only current running activity.

**this** - it's refers to the current class object

This refers to the current activity class object, and activity inherits context, so this must be used where context or activity can be used.

Answer (score 1):

From this [docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

I understood that you should use:

> Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity

Answer (score 1):

A `Context` is:

- an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system.
- It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as
  up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities,
  broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.