# IllegalStateException while ahowing Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am new to Android and may be what i am asking is very silly one..so please forgive me

To create AlertDialog.... standard way is to call

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context here....).create();
```

then
        alertDialog.show();

But i tried via 3 ways...

### way 1

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
```

### way 2

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

### way 3

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getApplicationContext()).create();
```

First 2 works fine but 3rd one gives illegalSTateException......

so my query is why it is giving that????

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question's answer will help you understand the different types of contexts in android

[Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-g)

Related to your error, android probably don't want your AlertDialog to be tied to the entire app context, but just to the activity's.

Comment: Let me write what i have understood is this...

this/ MainActivity.this ====> it get context wrt to Activity which is required

But by using getApplicationContext()....it is getting context in which application is running ..which is not required...

Comment: Activity extends ContextWrapper, therefore getContext(), this and Activity.this are the same reference. getApplicationContext as the docs says ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29 ) is tied to the application process, instead of the current component, in your case, your activity.