# WindowManager BadTokenException when showing custom dialog android

Tags: android

When i run my code i get this error:

```
  : E/InputEventReceiver(1363): Exception dispatching input event.

  : E/MessageQueue-JNI(1363): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

  : D/dalvikvm(1363): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1898K, 30% free 4921K/6992K, paused 78ms+107ms, total 413ms

  : E/MessageQueue-JNI(1363):  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for  an application

  : E/MessageQueue-JNI(1363):at  com.example.ikmantest2.MainActivity$6.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:269)
```

And this is the code that i get error:

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_dialog_layout);


            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            imageView=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.bigger_image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(exListAdapter.getImageByPosition(lastClickedGroup, arg2));
            pre=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_pre);
            back=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            next=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_next); 

            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            pre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            /*this is line number 269 as in error code*/  dialog.show();
        }

    });
```

So how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**do this way**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Direct hit------->>It's working.Can you tell me what happening there.Why getBaseContext() not work?

Comment: you can not use baseContext() because it refers to other context and UI need a current context so you were getting getBaseContext() null

Comment: for more info visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-g

Comment: Worth noting that this can still happen with an activity context.

Answer (score 2):

change final

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
```

to

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when wrong context is passed, simply change the `Dailog context to activity context`.

Use:

> final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

Instead:

> final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());

Comment: Can you tell me what happening there.It's work as previous answer.Why getBaseContext() not work?

Comment: You are passing correct context to your dialog, which cause error, refer some documents regarding `types of Context`

Answer (score 0):

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

or

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0):

A Dialog can be showed by an Activity and not (directly) by the Application (and principally not by a Service), therefore the Dialog's constructor expects the Context of the Activity and not the Context of the Application.

If you know the name of your activity, then

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this);
```

of course works.

But if you don't want to burn the name of your Activity in your code, use this snippets:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Context context; // for context of the application
Context acontext; // for context of the activity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext(); // Don't use for Dialog
    acontext = this; // Use for Dialog
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Dialog block started
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(acontext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });     
    dialog.show();
    // Dialog block ended
}}
```