# What could be alternative without need to keep context?

Tags: android, android-context

In a class which is not Activity and thus doesn't have a Context I need to store a file like:

```
public static void saveAvatar(String fileName, Bitmap avatar) {
    if (avatar == null)
        return;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName + ".jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        avatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[To make it work I need to keep a context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in a class because I'm calling this method from another class which doesn't have a context either. Is there a way to do it without context like using ContentResolver or something like?

Comment: Just pass in your context as a parameter.

Comment: @dymmeh Never pass a context to anything which is static - memory leak heaven!  @Stan - read the documentation for `getApplicationContext`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Context of your application class. Use the following template to be able to use your application class as a singleton:

```
private static MyApplication instance;

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
  return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  instance = this;
}
```

Now, you can change your code to the following:

```
public static void saveAvatar(String fileName, Bitmap avatar) {
    if (avatar == null)
        return;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = MyApplication.getInstance().openFileOutput(fileName + ".jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        avatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways.

1)Pass in a context in the constructor

2)Pass in the file or the directory in the constructor and just create the file using the standard java apis.

Comment: If this is the only reason the Context is needed, then obtaining the directory path using it once and passing *that* around as in your (2) sounds like a better idea.