# How to pass an Object with annotation?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use annotated class as parameters like below:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContextHolder {
}

@ContextHolder
class Foo extends Context {
}

// In some other place
protected Context getContext(ActionHandler handler) {
    if (handler.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Context.class)) {
        return (Context) handler;
    }
    for (Method m : handler.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(Context.class)) {
            try {
                return (Context) m.invoke(handler);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                ALog.w("", e);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                ALog.w("", e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                ALog.w("", e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    ALog.e("Can't find Context in passed ActionHandler");
    return null;
}

Foo foo = ...;
getContext(foo?)
```

The problem is I don't know how to call `getContext()`. Simply passing foo results compile error.

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `getContext` expects an argument of type `ActionHandler`. Is `Foo` an `ActionHandler`? Is `Foo` what you should be passing in or what you should be getting out?

Comment: I don't understand what your code has to do with annotations beside the fact that there are annotated classes. And if you get exceptions you have to include the logcat in your question. Without it we can just guess what the problem might be.

Comment: `Foo` is an `ActionHandler`, and I want to use annotations to prevent regular interface's implementing.

Comment: Check this for getContext : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and