# Where do these code snippets for DynamoDB go in my Android application?

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am creating an Android application that needs to store/retrieve data in DynamoDB. I created a DynamoDB table called "Schedules" and I created a Schedules class per[this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) tutorial. However, this tutorial is weirdly missing where/how to place authentication code and Object mapper code.

I used Amazon Cognito, created an identity pool, and got the resulting sample code, as referenced [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html) under the Providing AWS Credentials header, #4. Where is this code supposed to go? In its own class? In the activity where I'm displaying/creating the data from the table? If so, where (onCreate(), its own method, etc?). Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for pointing this out. We'll work to get the docs updated.

The credentials provider is passed to the DynamoDB client, which is in turn passed to the mapper.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddb);
```

Where this code goes will depend on your application, but it is a good practice to try to keep a single reference to the mapper and client, so in onCreate() or in a separate shared class is probably most appropriate.

Comment: In the sample Cognito code, it has the line: myActivity.getContext(). I added this code to an activity in the onCreate() method, but this.getContext() does not work, because getContext() is not a method for Activity. There is getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext(). How do I make this line work?

Comment: Which sample code are you looking at, and which line? As [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and) answers, each has different use cases, but it would help me if I saw what you were looking at.