# Toast message not shown

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I am trying to show a toast message in my application using the following code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Do you want to continue?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    try{
                        //This code generates an Activity Not Found exception   
                        }
                        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println("Activity Not Found Exception Raised");
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For the context I tried using getBaseContext, ActivityName.this also
                        }
                    }

            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            alert.show();
```

But this message is being shown only on few devices. I've tested this code on HTC One X having Android version 4.2.2 which is working.

The same code if I test on Micromax A63 which is also having Android 4.2.2, but it doesn't work on it.

I've searched over Internet for this kind of errors and they are mostly telling about the app notification disabling option in the settings menu. But my application notification are not disabled.

**EDIT**

I'm doing it inside an `AlertDialog`

Can someone help me solve this issue.

Comment: Change the `Context` and try again...

Comment: try classname.this instead of getapplicationcontext

Comment: Your line of code is correct, instead of using "getApplicationContext()" try using "YourClassName.this"

Comment: did you get any error ? be sure you call this line on UI thread, your code is ok problem must be in some where else

Comment: show ur full code pls..

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @prince try use `ActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I've tried that tooo... But got the same result.

Comment: are you sure you get `ActivityNotFoundException`? try put log statement in code and check that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I've checked that also, it enters that part of the code. The problem is it shows the toast message on other device.

Answer (score 15):

In case you haven't figured this out yet, make sure you haven't disabled notifications for the application in question; this also disables toasts.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

Comment: This was very easy to miss! What am not certain about though, is that while enabling notifications solved this for the entire app - all activities that is, they were mysteriously working inside of one of the adapters!

Comment: Wow! this saves me some hours of stress

Comment: Thanks, bro! I've disabled the notifications long time ago and I totally forgot about that.

Comment: 2012 - 2019. Bug is still here

Answer (score 4):

If you are using it in an activity then use:

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And if 
You are using it for fragments then:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR in Adapter

```
Toast.makeText(context, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Note: here in adapter the context means the context you declared in your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

OR

```
Toast.makeText(PreferenceActivity.this, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); `
```

For more details .Check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Do you want to continue?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    try{
                        //This code generates an Activity Not Found exception   
                        }
                        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println("Activity Not Found Exception Raised");
                           ShowToast();
                        }
                    }

            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            alert.show();

}

public void ShowToast()
{
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For the context I tried using getBaseContext, ActivityName.this also
}
```

Comment: same result on using `getBaseContext()`. I'm using this in a `PreferenceActivity`

Comment: set ShowToast() outside the dialog. Tell me now it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Context context;

1.Then call and initialize on `OnCreate()`

```
context=this; (Use in Activity)

context=this.getActivity(); (Use in Fragment)
```

Then use

```
Toast.makeText(context, "My Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getBaseContext`.