# Toast not showing in Android Q

Tags: android, toast, android-10.0

`Toast` does not work in **Android Q**. Is there any change on `Toast`? I couldn't find any release note for `Toast`.
My code is simple.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun onButtonClick(view: View) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onButtonClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

This works fine with Android Pie, but no luck with Android Q.
What happened to `Toast`??

Comment: I found that `Toast` works fine on emulator with Android Q. I think this is a bug of current version of Android. `Toast` won't work on device only. In my case, it was Pixel 3 XL.

Comment: I have had no problems with `Toast` working on a Pixel running Q (Beta 1 or Beta 2).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672191/why-toast-is-not-compatible-with-android-28/73676482#73676482

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rebooting device worked for me..

Comment: any idea what happened actually?

Comment: Not really. I couldn't find any clue.. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: I've faced the same problem. And your advice was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine some times emulator's system ui stops working and after reboot it works properly

Answer (score 0):

As described in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785345/4079010), make sure you haven't disabled notifications for the application. Go to App settings and see that notifications are enabled.

Comment: No, every notification channels are enabled.

Comment: As I commented to my question, it works on emulator. I tried setGravity as you mentioned, but it doesn't worked neither.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me. however you never posted that it works on emulator before posting comment here. thanks