# Why Toast is not compatible with Android 28+?

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

why does standard form Toast (also in current google android online docs)
give "false caller" error for an app in Android compileSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion 28. Using getApplicationContext() does not matter.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

...

  OnClickListener captureListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "pop-up text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  };

}
```

error line, on real android-11 device:

`V/Toast: Toast SHOW: android.widget.Toast@86d08e5 view = android.widget.LinearLayout{540bfba V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} pkg: com.example.app TextToast? false caller: com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onClick:211 ...`

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.3.1"
}
```

Comment: Pl share the complete error logcat.

Comment: added the error line

Comment: Is it an error (throws and the app stops) or just a message it prints to the log? If an actual throw, include the *full* stack trace.

Comment: the program stops working after that, compiled to a previous ancient android version work just fine,  the program does not stop working.

its not an actual throw.

Comment: Ok, then include the full stack trace. What you posted is an output from a `Log.v` call ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4bed684c939b0f8809ef404b8609fe4ef849263/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java#404)) - not an actual error. Your statement is contradictory though - you say the program stops working, but that it is not an actual throw. A program doesn't just "stop working" without throwing or crashing, unless you mean something else by "stop working" (e.g. doesn't show the toast?)

Comment: for the record, I'm trying to update https://github.com/hongxiongncsu/IMU-image-recorder-android to compile on latest android studio, the recent android studio cannot directly compile to old android <28 sdk version the code for some support reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the `Toast.makeText()` code were made starting with Android 11+ with the introduction of the Compatibility **CHANGE_TEXT_TOASTS_IN_THE_SYSTEM** check.

```java
    /**
     * Make a standard toast to display using the specified looper.
     * If looper is null, Looper.myLooper() is used.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public static Toast makeText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable Looper looper,
            @NonNull CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
        if (Compatibility.isChangeEnabled(CHANGE_TEXT_TOASTS_IN_THE_SYSTEM)) {
            Toast result = new Toast(context, looper);
            result.mText = text;
            result.mDuration = duration;
            return result;
        } else {
            Toast result = new Toast(context, looper);
            View v = ToastPresenter.getTextToastView(context, text);
            result.mNextView = v;
            result.mDuration = duration;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

> CHANGE_TEXT_TOASTS_IN_THE_SYSTEM Change ID: 147798919
>
> Default state: Enabled for apps that target Android 11 (API level 30)
> or higher.
>
> Text toasts are now rendered by the SystemUI instead of in-app. This
> prevents apps from circumventing restrictions on posting custom toasts
> in the background.
>
> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/compat-framework-changes#change_text_toasts_in_the_system

What is SystemUI?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/README.md

As Myrick Chow explained, you must now instantiate a Toast (first method) rather than using the static Toast object (second method), as shown below.

```java
// Method 1: Public constructor
val simpleToast = Toast(this)

// Method 2: Static constructor
val textToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Simple toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

https://itnext.io/android-11-toast-updates-7f1cd2245bc4

Comment: facepalm :) ahem