# getContext() method is undefined for the type MainActivity when get apps icon

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to get an icon of the installed app. Using the following way, I'm getting the error:

> The method getContext() is undefined for the type MainActivity

```
try{
   String pkg = "com.app.my";//your package name
   Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkg);
   imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
}
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ne) {

}
```

It would be very helpful if someone could guide me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641144/1892652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `getContext()`. `Activity` extends `Context`. Just call `getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkg)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` class extends `Context` .So just call `getContext();`
This will make use of the activities layout defined context.