# UnityPlayerActivity getContext() substitution

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Is there an alternative to the getContext in UnityPlayerActivity?

I want the code as shown below.

```
Activity.getContext()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer from [here](http://www.vortech.net/2013/03/accessing-the-android-activity-context-in-unity3d/)

```
using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
            playerActivityContext = actClass.GetStatic< AndroidJavaObject >("currentActivity");
        }
```

or you can use code below from [here](http://www.codestalkers.com/blog/android-plugins)

```
public class Main extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    public static Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            mContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[getContext()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) is not defined in an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html). It's used in a ***View*** to get a reference to the enclosing ***context***(an *Activity*).

Please read below Answer .I hope it will helps you.

> [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)