# Show resource with progressdialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can show resource in progressdialog three different way.

```
pDialog.setMessage(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));

pDialog.setMessage(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));

pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
```

Which one is the true way and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *true way*. You only need `Context`:

- `getResources()` when you are in `Activity` class (or `MyActivity.this.getResources()` when you are calling from inner class, while being in Activity class)
- `getActivity().getResources()` (or even `getContext().getResources()`) when you are in `Fragment` class
- `context.getResources()` when you pass `Context` through parameter
- `view.getContext().getResources()` when you get `Context` from your `View`

---

The following two have "equivalent `Context`", since you are in `Fragment` like I can assume by your question tag:

```
pDialog.setMessage(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));

pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
```

where

```
pDialog.setMessage(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
```

you get `Context` of entrie application.

Here some reference:

[Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and “this”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)