# Difference between getApplicationContext() and this in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I know this is a basic question but i have seen that using the method getApplicationContext() to get the context work at places where the "this" keyword does't work, especially inside an onClickListener. 
Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of an OnClickListener, `this` is the anonymous class of the OnClickListener, therefore not a Context.

Whereas calling that method works because it's from the Activity class.

Alternatively, `MyActivity.this` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

**`getActivity()`:** Used inside a `Fragment` to get the context of activity it is currently associated to.

**`this`:** Returns the context of current block in which it is called. If it is called inside an `onClickListener` then it would return the context of that listener, not the activity.

**`MyActivity.this`:** Returns the context of the activity. This can be used at the place of `getActivity()` as an alternate. (MyActivity should be read as the activity name you are using).