# Android Context Class more specific

Tags: android, class, android-intent, textview

For what purpose Context class is used in android?Please explain me in depth and be more specific .I read all other posts but none of them were specific enough to give me clear understanding.
I know Content class allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Like Here,
 *Intent intent=new Intent(this,new_class.class);*

why we are passing Main activity context into the Intent constructor call.what type of information does this activity context contain,how will it help it ,what type of resource access is it providing to it ?(with example please).
Similarly,
here,

*TextView textview=new TextView(this);*

Why TextView need activity context?How does it help it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10641257/793943 please check this ans

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android check this as well. It have some great explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already several good explanations of `Context` on Stackoverflow (see the linked questions and us the "search" feature. Also, the source code for Android is available on `grepcode.com` and you can look yourself if you are really interested. Why trust someone else's answer if you can look yourself? ;-)

However, I will answer your specific questions:

> ```
> Intent intent=new Intent(this,new_class.class);
> ```
>
> why we are passing Main activity context into the Intent constructor
>   call.what type of information does this activity context contain,how
>   will it help it ,what type of resource access is it providing to it
>   ?(with example please).

In this case (the 2-argument constructor for `Intent`), the `Context` parameter is only used to determine the **package name** of the target `Activity`. Assuming that the package name of your application is "com.example.app", and `MyActivity` is an `Activity of your application, the following code snippets are all functionally identical:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, "com.example.app.MyActivity");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, MyActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app", MyActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.MyActivity");
```

> Similarly, here,
>
> TextView textview=new TextView(this);
>
> Why TextView need activity context?How does it help it.

All `View`s need a `Context`. Think of the `Context` as the "owner of the View". This controls the lifetime of the `View`. In general, a `View` should have the same lifetime as its owning `Activity`, which is why you usually pass the `Activity` as the `Context` parameter when creating a `View`. When the `Activity` is destroyed, all of the owned `View`s are also destroyed. Additionally, the `View` uses the `Context` to gain access to resources (drawables, layouts, strings, themes, etc.).

Comment: Seems helpful and thanks for pointing out the error in my answer and clearing my misconception. Just one more doubt, why dont fragments or adapters, etc. have context even though they can control the UI (With parent activity's context)

Comment: And also any link (other than stack overflow answer) will be much appreciated as all the blogs and sites I have seen yet has created the misconception.

Comment: Fragments use the parent activity's `Context`, as you've stated. `Adapter` is an interface anyway. If you look at all the concrete implementations of `Adapter` (ie: `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`, `SimpleAdapter`), they all take a `Context` parameter in the constructor (this should be the `Activity Context`, because the adapter's lifetime is linked to the lifetime of the `Activity`.

Comment: I tend to read the Android source code to get my information, so I don't have a ready link for you. You can find the Android source code on `grepcode.com`. What articles and blog posts are you referring to? There's a lot of people out there who (incorrectly) think they know what they are talking about (unfortunately). I'm especially interested in where you got the idea that `Context` has anything to do with threading?

Answer (score 1):

It act as a Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

You can get all the information from delveloper's official documentation... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html