# Is it advisable to use ApplicationContext to create Notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it advisable to use `ApplicationContext` to create Notifications in Android? I have used the same in another one of my applications where I create notifications in a class which I create using the `StartActivityModalForResult()` API. I do get time and again crashes. Should I use `BaseContext()` instead?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I think this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10641257/5225620

Comment: No one will be able to help you without the crash log and a snippet of your code.