# Android: getContext() error

Tags: android, android-context

just a simple error I have but I am really having a hard time trying to solve this problem. why is this `getContext()` are not applied?

```
 public void ClearRecentPlayer() {

        mDbHelper = new DataConn(getContext()); //<---getContext() in redline(not applied)
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATS, 0);

        String selection = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATS + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { "0" };
        int c = db.update(
                FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME_PLAYER,
                v,
                selection,
                selectionArgs);
    }
```

and with this...

```
public class DataConn extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_egame.db";

    DataConn mDbHelper;

    public DataConn(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_EASY_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_HARD_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DIFF_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PLAYER_ENTRIES);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_EASY_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_HARD_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_DIFF_ENTRIES);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_PLAYER_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Comment: because that doesn't return to any context or that context is not pointing to the content where your method is, try `class.this` or `application.getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` whatever is available that will result to actually point the context where your method is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Comment: thought I was following a good tutorial... :-(( should I rebuild my code?

Comment: Question is unclear... Please show a [mcve] of all relevant code. Meaning the class definition of where you are calling that context method

Comment: I doubt your tutorial stores `DataConn mDbHelper;` within the `DataConn` class itself

Comment: @Jay that I wouldn't know, your question is very minimal as what cricket above mentioned, if you could provide a more detailed question, that might help

Comment: I already updated the code in my question. please refer above

Comment: @cricket_007 damn it is... :-((

Comment: We can't answer your question without seeing what type of class `ClearRecentPlayer()` is defined it. That will tell us (and you) why you can't call `getContext()`

Answer (score 3):

As explained here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10641257/2319627)

> •`View.getContext()`: Returns the context the view is currently
>   running in. Usually the currently active Activity.
>
> •`Activity.getApplicationContext()`: Returns the context for the
>   entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside
>   of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a
>   context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the
>   current Activity.
>
> •`ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()`: If you need access to a Context
>   from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper. The Context
>   referred to from inside that ContextWrapper is accessed via
>   getBaseContext.

So, it will be better to use `getApplicationContext()` when you are trying to use a DataBaseHelper.

And, you can call `getApplicationContext` from activity or service only, or from an instance of context. Like `activity.getApplicationContext()`

You need an application context for a Database helper class. So, pass a context to the database on initialization

ClearRecentPlayer method is in an activity? else, you have to pass the application context to the class from which you call `ClearRecentPlayer` method.

you can either create a member variable `.Context` in that class, or you can call the `ClearRecentPlayer` method as `ClearRecentPlayer (Context context)`

Comment: I cant. I can only use 'getContext()' in this class.. I dont know why

Comment: are you trying this in an activity?

Comment: You need an application context for a Database helper class. So, pass a context to the database on initialization

ClearRecentPlayer method is in an activity? else, you have to pass the application context to the class from which you call `ClearRecentPlayer` method.

you can either create a member variable `.Context` in that class, or you can call the `ClearRecentPlayer` method as `ClearRecentPlayer (Context context)`

Answer (score 2):

`getContext()` is only an available method of a `View`.

If your method is in that database class, you don't actually need the Context. Or any instance of `DataConn` within its own class.

```
public class DataConn extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_egame.db";

    private Context mContext;

    public DataConn(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    public void clearRecentPlayer() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATS, 0);

        String selection = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATS + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { "0" };
        int c = db.update(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME_PLAYER,
            v,
            selection,
            selectionArgs);
    }
```

Comment: I think I got the answer.
I changed the 'DataConn mDHelper;' to just 'this' and use 'getApplicationContext()' instead of 'getContext()' in different java class. Thank you @cricket_007

Comment: but the problem now is that the cursor is returning null. :-((

Comment: please help me. X-((

Comment: Help you with what? You don't need `getApplicationContext()` here. If you have a new problem related to this code, please post a new question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Try **getApplicationContext()** instead of **getContext()**   for activity/AppCompactActivity,