# How can I generate static String[] and get Strings from resource in self-defined class?

Tags: java, android, static, resources

```
public class StorageStrings {

    public static String[] keysPrefs = {getString(R.string.key_mod), getString(R.string.key_vel),getString(R.string.key_num)};
    public static String[] defaultValues = {getString(R.string.default_value_mod),getString(R.string.default_value_vel),getString(R.string.default_value_num)};
}
```

I want to store my Strings in this class.
But I cannot use getString() method to retrieve the String from the resource.

How can I get the String from resource in this self-defined class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it without an `android.content.Context` object.

So you can either

1. Pass a `Context` to the constructor of the self contained class; or
2. Save the application context somewhere in a static variable that you can then access from your self contained class (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and))

Answer (score 0):

If the function is in any Activity then you can use following code:

```
public class StorageStrings {

    public static String[] keysPrefs = {getString(R.string.key_mod), getString(R.string.key_vel),getString(R.string.key_num)};
    public static String[] defaultValues = {getString(R.string.default_value_mod),getResources().getString(R.string.default_value_vel),getResources().getString(R.string.default_value_num)};
}
```

If the function is not in any activity then you will need context of that activity and can use following code

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.default_value_num)
```

instead of

```
getResources().getString(R.string.default_value_num)};
```