# What is an example where you use getBaseContext()?

Tags: java, android

if i understand correctly, you use `getContext()` to get the context of a view object. You use activity context or `this` if you want to create a new object that exist as long as activity exist, if not the activity wont be destroyed and eventually lead to memory leaks. You use `getApplicationContext()` if you want a context that is tied to the global lifecycle of the application and should be used wherever we need to create a object that exist beyond the current activity.

Is my understanding correct ?

But what is `getBaseContext()` and where do you use it exactly.. One simple and solid example would be great

Answer (score 1):

View.getContext() usually returns the context the view of current Activity. ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()is used while accessing a Context from within another context example Activity.

See at - [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and] "this"7]: [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)