# Intent on imageview in recyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm facing an issue regarding intent in RecyclerView.
I just want intent on 1 imageView that is in my RecyclerView.

Error is:

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?
>                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1383)
>                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1370)
>                                                                         at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
>                                                                         at example.memories.MyAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:75)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4871)
>                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20365)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 07-13
>   01:55:31.033 20699-29708/example.memories E/NativeCrypto:
>   ssl=0x5578a74560 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f9844d228
>   arg=0x0 07-13 01:55:31.033 20699-29708/example.memories
>   E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5578a74560 cert_verify_callback calling
>   verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA

and my RecyclerView Adapter code is:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Upload> uploads;
    Upload upload;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        this.uploads = uploads;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         upload = uploads.get(position);

       holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploads.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView,shareImage;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

           textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            shareImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);

            shareImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                   context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share memories:"));

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Kindly guide me. how can i achieve this?

Comment: what context are you passing to this adapter?

Comment: @santalu in other java file where i'm setting adapter, i'm passing getApplicationContext

Comment: That's the issue. Don't pass `getApplicationContext()` to your adapter. Just pass your activity's context and you don't even need to `shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` do this.

Comment: Thanks Buddy ! Problem solved.!
can you help me in one more problem?

Comment: Of course but please post another question.

Comment: sure. i'll post another question

Comment: @santalu done posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass `getApplicationContext()` to your adapter. Just pass your activity's context and you don't even need to `shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` do this.

And beware when using application context. 
I really suggest you to read [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 0):

Either pass in an Activity context instead of an Application context when you construct MyAdapter, or add the following line before you call context.startActivity:

```
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```