# why do i have a GetActivity context error?

Tags: java, android

Sorry i am a beginner and i am not sure why there is this error which is at the get activity `context` line,this is the code please help me out here,i am trying to activate a `ringtone` from the `broadcast receiver` program(alarm)

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;

Ringtone ringTone;
Uri uriRingtone;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt);
    boolean useNotification = prefs.getBoolean("use_notification", true);

    uriRingtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

    ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getactivityContext(), uriRingtone);
    ringTone.play();

    if (useNotification) {
        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)
                ctxt.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, new Intent(ctxt, AlarmActivity.class), 0);
        Notification note = new Notification.Builder(ctxt)
                .setContentTitle("Restaurant List")
                .setContentText("It's time for lunch!")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setContentIntent(i)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, AlarmActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        ctxt.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: change getactivityContext() to ctxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ctxt, uriRingtone);
```

Instead of this

```
ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getactivityContext(), uriRingtone);
```

Comment: what's the difference between ctxt and getactivitycontext()?

Comment: @Novice this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Comment: @Novice no method for getting context like `getactivitycontext()`