# How to create a dialog outside MainActivity in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to insert an alert dialog into my android app. 
It's fine when I follow the tutorial to add it in a simple project, which only has a `MainActivity.java`, `activity_main.xml` and a `layout` xml.

However, when I want to insert the code into my project, I get some questions. 
My code is:

```
android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Exit?")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure want to QUIT ?")
                        .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                pmaControllerManager.OnExit();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
```

There is a warning symbol in the **this** in the first line.
How could I fix it?
p.s. below is the function where I call **showDialog**(I call it in buttons[5]):

```
private void setbutton()
{
    buttons[0]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button0);
    buttons[1]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttons[2]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[3]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[4]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttons[5]=(ImageButton)menu.findViewById(R.id.button5);

    buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.screen);
    buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sketch);
    buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.importdraw);
    buttons[4].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setting);
    buttons[5].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out);
    center.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.noticeicon_using);

    /*center.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(click)
            {
                closemenu();
                //mode=false;
            }
            else
            {
                openmenu();
                //mode=true;
            }
            click=!click;
        }
    });*/
    center.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        boolean isMove=false;
        int touchy,touchx,y;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action=motionEvent.getAction();
            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                y=params.y;
                //Log.i("y:",String.valueOf(y));
                touchy=(int)motionEvent.getRawY();
                touchx=(int)motionEvent.getRawX();
            }
            else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                if(Math.abs(motionEvent.getRawX()-touchx)<30)
                {
                    isMove=true;
                    params.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
                    params.y=y+(int)motionEvent.getRawY()-touchy;
                    wm.updateViewLayout(center,params);
                    wm.updateViewLayout(menu,params);
                }
            }
            else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                if(!isMove)
                {
                    if(click)
                    {
                        closemenu();
                        //mode=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        openmenu();
                        //mode=true;
                    }
                    click=!click;
                }
                else
                    isMove=false;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    buttons[1].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.screen_focus);
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.screen);
                pmaControllerManager.newTask("screen");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    buttons[2].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sketch_focus);
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sketch);
                pmaControllerManager.newTask("sketch");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    buttons[3].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.importdraw_focus);
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.importdraw);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    buttons[4].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttons[4].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setting_focus);
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buttons[4].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.setting);
                pmaControllerManager.Setting();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    buttons[5].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttons[5].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exit_focus);
            else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                buttons[5].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out);
                shoaDialog(menuwindow.this);
                pmaControllerManager.OnExit();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: show your full code

Comment: where did you put this code?

Comment: Should I paste all the class for you? Or just the function?

Answer (score 2):

Pass `Context` instead of `this` because `this` is a reference to the **current** object. It means if you call it for example from lambda `this` will be a reference of object which is extended from anonymous class.

so you can make method like

```
public void showDialog(Context context) {
    AlertDialog alartDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).
           ...
           .show();
}
```

and then call it like

```
showDialog(MainActivity.this); //for activity
showDialog(MainFragment.this.getActivity()); //for fragment
```

By the way better to make something like Util class for it:

```
class DialogUtil {
   public static void showDialog(Context context) {
             AlertDialog alartDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).
           ...
           .show();
   }
}
```

Then call it like

```
DialogUtil.showDialog(MainActivity.this); //for activity
DialogUtil.showDialog(MainFragment.this.getActivity()); //for fragment
```

UPDATE

Instead of calling it like:

```
shoaDialog(menuwindow.this);
```

You can pass Context as I described above or you can get it from View:

```
buttons[5].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //some code here
        showDialog(v.getContext());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I have created a new method but I cannot call **showDialog()** in other function. Is it correct to call it in other function?

Comment: @Ron Make it static. So you can call it from everywhere. I will give example

Comment: @Ron just wrap it like this. And yeah its correct to call in other functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. It is fine when I make the method with or without **static**. However, I just cannot call it in other function.
p.s. I've edited my post and add where I call it. THX.

Answer (score 0):

replace `this` to `MainActivity.this` like :

> android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new
>   android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I've tried it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this` with `MainActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()`

```
android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
```

If you are using dialog look below :

**For Activity :** `ActivityName.this`

```
android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
```

**For Fragment :** `getActivity()`

```
 android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
```

**For Adapter :** `Context context;`

```
android.app.AlertDialog alartDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Also, Look into this [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Answer (score 0):

The AltertDialog requires a context and you are passing it the activity. Try using

```
new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
```

instead.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I've tried it, but it doesn't work.