# what is the new method for changing textview color in android programaticallly

Tags: java, android, xml, text, colors

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Activity

public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    TextView textView = new TextView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    name.setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name")));
    name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));
```

I tried

```
name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

  name.setTextColor(color.WHITE);

  name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But not working... please help.................................................................

Comment: Please specify what API version are you using when you are talking about new one.

Comment: You can try this name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)

Comment: Try with other colors like RED, BLUE, BLACK. You are trying White text on White background.

Comment: provide your full code with xml and java then find any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working..

```
public class LayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can access in class anywhere you can also make local level.

Comment: This is what i tried at first... didnt work

Comment: it will work i tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_1));
```

This should work for most Api versions

Comment: `getResources().getColor()` is deprecated.

Comment: what is view supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

`getResources().getColor()` is deprecated. Use this

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_name_id);
name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
```

Comment: getColor(int) on a null object reference

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: what should come in place of activity? and getapplicationcontext should come in place of context right?

Comment: that's just a example. Check the updated answer again.

Comment: looks like you are confused with the `getApplicationContext()` or `getContext()`. Refer to this link for more explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Comment: cannot resolve symbol context

Comment: you need to use `getApplicationContext()`. by the way I have mentioned one link for you in my comment. I recommend you to go through that

Comment: @JessicaMorgan Just for record consider accepting solution which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) declaration and initialization in your activity.
Declare it as a variable of your activity, and initialize it after calling `setContentView()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mNameTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_launch);
        mNameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        // remaining codes
       mNameTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this.... not working dude.... i obviously hav declared and initialised

Comment: post your full activity code

Comment: Done..............

Answer (score 0):

Try this method it's work fine on all Api levels.

```
public int _getColor(int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(this, id);
    } else {
        return getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```