# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied with two options

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I have the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` declaration below:

```
    private void updateList() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(
                User.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                ListOnlineViewHolder.class,
                counterRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListOnlineViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User model) {
                holder.txtEmail.setText((model.getEmail()));
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ListOnlineViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listOnline.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The declaration of `adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>` gives an error of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied.` I am aware that I need to build `FirebaseRecyclerOptions.` How do I build 2 options?

Comment: what do u mean 2 options

Comment: Do I have to declare  `FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
                        .setQuery(category, Category.class)
                        .build();` twice?

Comment: No only once then u declare the recycleradapter

Comment: which one do I declare then? `User.class,`, `ListOnlineViewHolder.class`?

Answer (score 0):

First, configure the adapter by building FirebaseRecyclerOptions.For example:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                        .setQuery(query, User.class)
                        .build();
```

Next create the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter object. You should already have a ViewHolder subclass for displaying each item. For example:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public ListOnlineViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
        // layout called R.layout.message for each item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.message, parent, false);

        return new ListOnlineViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(ListOnlineViewHolder holder, int position, User model) {

    }
};
```

Check here for more info:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: what is the parent in this case?

Comment: Parent is of type viewgroup, you use it to call getContext() since the from method takes an instance of context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and

Comment: have you checked the answer?

Comment: yes, I did. Thanks for the answer. But where do I put `ListOnlineViewHolder.class, counterRef` in the newer version of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: here `.setQuery(counterRef, User.class)` , regarding the `ListOnlineViewHolder.class` just copy the answer

Comment: @IsaakNewton Since the answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as correct, thank you!